# Executing other python scripts gives NameError exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import

I have two .py scripts on the same folder, and I have a function like this on one:

```
def combat_menu():
    exec("combat.py")
```

Theese scripts are named dungeon.py(the one im executing from) and combat.py.

When I execute this function this error appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Documents\piton\Dungeon\dungeon_Data\dungeon.py", line 25, in combat_menu
    exec("combat.py")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'combat' is not defined
```

I execute this function from a tkinter button widget like this:

```
event_button = t.Button(root, text="Open CM", command=combat_menu)
```

I have tried importing the code, but this gives ImportError.

Comment: what are the names of your two .py files?

Comment: Please post the relevant code as a [mre] so people (like me ;-) can have a look at it.

Comment: made some changes, hope it helps!

Comment: you probably want to import it. Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files?

Comment: it's usually advisable to specify the full path to the executing file - sometimes the environment changes the root location in which files are searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec()` function supports dynamic execution of Python code. It is not executing a shell command. To execute a shell command, in your case calling another python file. Instead you can use for example:

```
os.system(*cmd*) ->
os.system('combat.py')
```