# Python Import successful but I get NameError

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am running the python interpreter from the same directory where the imported file `my_module.py` resides. When I try to use the function defined in the imported file using only the function name `print_hi`, I get a `NameError` error message. But it works fine if I reference the function using `my_module.print_hi`

Is there a way to make this work without referencing the module file name?

Is there a way to make this work without using the `from` keyword in the import statement?

```
PS C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\General\importing> type my_module.py
def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}')
PS C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\General\importing> python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_module
>>> print_hi('joe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'print_hi' is not defined
>>> my_module.print_hi('joe')
Hi, joe
>>>
```

Comment: Wouldn't a from import solve your problem: `from my_module import print_hi` or the all import (not recommended) `from my_module import *` ?

Comment: It does solve the problem, but I wounder why the ```import```statement without the ```from``` keyword does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to your `print_hi` function without using the module name, you must import it explicitly or import everything from the module:

```
from my_module import print_hi
# or import everything:
from my_module import *
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [from keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_from.asp)

```
from my_module import print_hi
print_hi('Joe')
```

From is used to import only a specified section from a module.