# Python/Jupyter Notebook Not finding modules...?

Tags: python, import, module

I just got done writing a pretty good rock paper scissors game and now when I try to import it and run the cell I'm getting this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8d3be5084430> in <module>
----> 1 import RPSgame.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPSgame.py'; 'RPSgame' is not a package
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it? I'm running Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda Navigator

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to how you are importing the .py file
This link might help: [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 0):

You shall try this:

```
import .RPSgame
```

Comment: This doesnt throw an error but it doesn't do what i've written either

Comment: What do you want it to do