# How to import only those functions from module which I am using (pycharm)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

```
import time

time.time()
time.sleep()
```

So for example I imported time and using only 2 functions from this module. Is there a hotkey or plugin to import only this functions automaticly and pop module name every time I used some function from there, without manually chainging every line.

What I am trying to get is

```
from time import time,sleep

time()
sleep()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different configuration, depending on your needs I suggest you to go through this official JetBrains documentations about

### [Auto import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html).

> To configure auto-import, in the Settings/Preferences dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
> , go to Editor | General | Auto Import, and use the corresponding XML, Python, and TypeScript/JavaScript options.

To enable / change the short cut, do the following:

1. Go to PyCharm -> Preferences
2. Check “Show Import Popup”
3. Next, look up the keyboard shortcut for auto-completion and change it to whatever shortcut you’d like to use.

When you tap this shortcut twice you will get the **special auto-import dropdown**

Or also

> You can define your preferred import style for Python code by using the following options available on the Auto Import page of the project settings (Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import).