# How to create a separate class for a custom function?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have to find user_id and order_id in the message, but I want to make a separate class for this search. I just want to optimise my code.

I have highlighted a part of the code(#-----) that I would like to cram into a separate file, but since I am a beginner I do not understand how it could be implemented. Tell me, please or at least a similar example to figure it out for yourself.

This is my code:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="accept_ord", state=None)
    async def process_order_callback_4(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    answ_date_2=query.data

#------------
    #find the text from message
    text = str(query.message.text)
    #find id_order from the text of the message
    id = text.split('\n')[0].split("№ ")[1]
    #from str to int
    id_1 = int(re.search('\d+', id).group(0))
    #find id_user from table_2 in db
    cl_id = str(db.get_user_id_admin(id_1))
    #from str to int
    cl_id_1 = int(re.search('\d+', cl_id).group(0))
    #find id_user from table_1 in db
    user_id = str(db.get_user_telegram_id_admin(cl_id_1))
    user_id_clear=int(re.search('\d+', user_id).group(0))
    #------------

    await bot.send_message(user_id_clear,
                           text=f'The status of the order has been change №{id_1} изменен!\n\nPlease check main menu (/start)')
    if answ_date_2 == "accept_ord":
        status = 2
        db.set_new_status(id_1, status)

        await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, text=f'The order №{id_1} has been assepted.', reply_markup=nav.back_admin_menu_order)
```

It looks kreepy, but it works, hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid obsessing about classes; a class has a distinct theory that should not be abused. However, as you noted, your code appears to be a bit lengthy, and I would suggest the following:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="accept_ord", state=None)
async def process_order_callback_4(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    answ_date_2=query.data

    #------------
    id_1, user_id_clear = await __mySearch(query)
    #------------
    
    await bot.send_message(user_id_clear,
                           text=f'The status of the order has been change №{id_1} изменен!\n\nPlease check main menu (/start)')
    if answ_date_2 == "accept_ord":
        status = 2
        db.set_new_status(id_1, status)
    
        await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, text=f'The order №{id_1} has been assepted.', reply_markup=nav.back_admin_menu_order)


async def __mySearch(query):
    #find the text from message
    text = str(query.message.text)
    #find id_order from the text of the message
    id = text.split('\n')[0].split("№ ")[1]
    #from str to int
    id_1 = int(re.search('\d+', id).group(0))
    #find id_user from table_2 in db
    cl_id = str(db.get_user_id_admin(id_1))
    #from str to int
    cl_id_1 = int(re.search('\d+', cl_id).group(0))
    #find id_user from table_1 in db
    user_id = str(db.get_user_telegram_id_admin(cl_id_1))
    user_id_clear = int(re.search('\d+', user_id).group(0))
    return id_1, user_id_clear
```

*Note: For some tasks, it is acceptable to construct a utils.py that does the task generically with the parameters provided and returns the desired result. It could be extracted into another file and called within yours such as `import myFile` (refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349998/9814037) for more information)*