# Why I can't import module from the same directory in python

Tags: python, package

Project structure
test/
--test.py
--pkg/
----p1.py
----p2.py

test.py

```
import pkg.p1  
pkg.p1.print_p1()
```

p1.py

```
import p2  
def print_p1():  
  print('in p1')  
  p2.print_p2()
```

p2.py

```
def print_p2():  
    print('in p2')
```

When I run test.py, I gets ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p2'.
Tried adding empty __init__.py but still no luck. Any expert can help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work if in p1 if you do import pkg.p2?

Comment: @Hippolippo yes, it works. there is no error from p1.py

Comment: You are not using p2 in your test.py file. so the error is related to using p2 in yout p1.py file

Comment: check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Comment: @WilliamFung then just do that instead

Comment: @nCoder  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "h:\python\playground-main\test\pkg\p1.py", line 3, in <module>  
    from pkg.p2 import print_p2  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'  
I got this error

Comment: fyi, in sys.path it contains 'h:\\python\\playground-main\\test', I don't understand why when test.py call p1.py, it throws an error but it doesn't happen when I run p1.py itself

Comment: This was assuming you have the __ init __.py in your pkg directory as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your p1.py file to this and add a **init**.py in your pkg directory:

```
from pkg.p2 import print_p2
def print_p1():
  print('in p1')
  print_p2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding `from .p2 import print_p2` into `p1.py` would make `test.py` work, though `p1.py` itself would have error

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Thanks all for your help