# How to import other Python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have this file, `abc.py`:

```
def asb():
    print("Hello, ")

def xyz():
    print("World!")
```

In my `main.py` file,

```
from abc import asb

from abc import xyz
```

I want to import both `asb` and `abc` from `abc.py` without using separate lines.

I assume it's going to be something like this:

```
from abc import asb and xyz
```

Comment: The title may have to be more specific. For the general approach, see the canonical *[How can I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/)*.

Answer (score 2):

*Taken from Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html):*

> There is a variant of the import statement that imports names from a module directly into the importing module’s symbol table. For example:

```
>>> from fibo import fib, fib2
>>> fib(500)
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377
```

In your case, this would be

```
>>> from abc import asb, xyz
```

If you need to import many functions, I would suggest using:

```
>>> import abc
>>> abc.asb()
>>> abc.xyz()
```

or, if your abc is too long, use an alias:

```
>>> import abc as m
>>> m.asb()
>>> m.xyz()
```

instead of:

```
>>> from abc import *
```

as this will pollute your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from abc import asb, xyz
```

Or to import all functions:

```
from abc import *
```

Do refer to websites. They give lots of examples.
For example, *[Python – Call function from another file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-file/)*

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your function names using comma—'`,`':

```
from datetime import datetime, date
```

So in your case, you will have:

```
from abc import asb, xyz
```