# ModuleNotFoundError: Could not find python module

Tags: python-3.x

I got an `ModuleNotFoundError` error as seen below:

```
sample % python3 sample1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "sample1.py", line 4, in <module>
       from util_lib.helper1 import helper1_print 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util_lib' 
sample %
```

---

```
.../Testing/sample/:
            sample1.py (calls helper1.helper1_print())
 
 .../Testing/util_lib/:
        helper1.py (has helper1_print())
```

#### Codes

**sample1.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Absolute/Path/Testing/util_lib')
from util_lib.helper1 import helper1_print
helper1_print()


**util_lab/helper1.py:**
def helper1_print():
        print("Helper 1 Print")
```

Am I missing something?

---

I still have error when I used relative path instead of absolute path, see below:

sample1.py

---

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '../Testing')
from util_lib.helper1 import helper1_print

helper1_print()
```

---

### Error:

```
sample % python sample1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from util_lib.helper1 import helper1_print
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util_lib'
sample %
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: This is a common question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an issue while you are inserting `path` to `sys.path` as I see `sample` and `util_lib` directories are subdirectories of `Testing` not `API_Testing`

So instead of

```py
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/pluu/PycharmProjects/API_Testing/util_lib')
```

try

```py
sys.path.append("abs/path/to/Testing")
```

Comment: Thanks @Lone Samurai, see new errors in post above when I used relative instead of absolute path.

Comment: Manipulating sys.path from your code is not the right solution.