# How to save a python script into a local directory and call it with an import statement?

Tags: python, module

I am brand new to creating modules. I am working with a large Jupyter Lab (JL) file with lots of custom functions. I would like to take those functions, save them in a python file in the same working directory that my JL file is pulling data from, and import them as functions. I don't want to save them to the PIP package manager just yet; I just want to save them as local packages for now.

The functions would be in a .py file in a format similar to this:

```
def func1(x,y,z):
    """
    x = custom input
    y = custom imput
    z = custom input
    """
    
    do stuff


def func2(x,y,z):
    """
    x = custom input
    y = custom imput
    z = custom input
    """
    
    do stuff

def func3(x,y,z):
    """
    x = custom input
    y = custom imput
    z = custom input
    """
    
    do stuff

def func4(x,y,z):
    """
    x = custom input
    y = custom imput
    z = custom input
    """
    
    do stuff
```

I would save this in a python file such as "custom_func.py" and save it in the same directory as my JL file.

After saving the python file, what do I need to do so that I can import this as a custom local package? I have seen that you need to do something with `__init__.py`, but I'm just not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After saving the python file, what do I need to do so that I can import this as a custom local package?

You don't have to do anything else.  You can bring the function into your namespace from the script "custom_func.py" into the JupyterLab notebook.
Did you try:

```py
from custom_func import func1, func2, func3, func4
```

Now you can use each of those functions in your notebook as if they had been written in your notebook. For example, `result = func4(5,6,7)`.

Or alternatively, you can bring in the entire `custom_func` script and call it by reference to the name of the imported file followed by a dot followed by the function, like `module_name.function_name`:

```py
import custom_func
my_result = custom_func.func1(1,2,3)
```

I just adapted something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712291/8508004) to your example. You may want to look over that post as it may give you other options you prefer. The same things works in a script as well, which is what that post was about.

---

One of the reasons you may want to limit what you bring in is so you don't clobber what you have in your namespace already. Imagine you already had a `func3` defined. If you brought in a `func3` by the first method I suggested, you'd probably note that was going on and act accordingly.  Maybe rename your other function. If you did `from custom_func import *`, you **might not notice** you just replaced `func3`.  If you import the second way I suggested, the new functions are under the module name reference, and so that helps eliminate there being two `func3`. Because one will just be `func3` and one is `custom_func.func3`. However, often the first option I proposed is preferable so that you keep your namespace as clean as possible.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for your help.