# Python file can't import some functions from the other python file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a problem i have `standards.py` file which consists of the imports which needed to execute functions from withing and multiple functions. I want to import those functions in the other file. But for some reason two functions cannot be imported from the `standards.py` for some unknown reason.

But when I run the exact same code via the Jupyter notebook (just copy the file content which also imports `standards.py`) everything works and there's no problem, I just use `from standards import *`. But when I run file from the VSCode this becomes a problem.

In fact I want to wrap it up into `Pyinstaller` using `--onefile` method. But as well, when I run `.exe` that is created it throws an error with an import.

I checked spelling, I added an empty `__init__.py` file into the file. I do keep both files in the same directory in the sam folder. And yes, I tried to import it as `from standards import func_a, func_b`.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Clearing your namespace each time? Remember Python tries to save importing what it already did and so updates don't get reflected by default. Have you tried using the Python console in VSCode or separate (?) to debug and run the import step? Checked with `dir()` before & after the test? Tried changing the name of the script from `standard` to something more obscure so there's no chance of a conflict in your path being involved? Tried simpler functions and imports in same places? Checked working directory and environment thoroughly?

Comment: @Wayne I tried changing name and it didn't help me out. Though, seems like the directory is different and therefore this happens. At the same time I tried to insert
```python
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)```
In the code both for `__init__.py` and main script but it didn't help for some reason.

Comment: "Though, seems like the directory is different and therefore this happens." Yes, keeping your working directory straight can be tricky. About what you tried inserting.... I cannot tell if you have some syntax issue or not in what you are inserting because of the way comments may handle code blocks. Always best to add it to your question and indicate an update heading above it and then reference it in the comment. Did you try inserting that code in the actual file you are importing from? I wouldn't deal with `__init__.py` yet. Get to the point ...

Comment: <comment> you can just import a normal script if you aren't there already. I cannot tell from what you wrote if that works or not.  (For sorting this out, I have some simple code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019554/8508004) you can try using Python on the console. Nevermind it says Jupyter, you should be able to do same with Python.) Then you can add fancy packaging stuff later like `__init__.py` later. (I thought `__init__.py` was not longer critical although it remains common.)