# ImportError: Unble to import a function from a python file

Tags: python, import

I was trying to import "progress_bar" function from mutils1.py

```
from mutils1 import progress_bar
```

the error happens:

```
 Traceback (most 
    recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name 'progress_bar' from 'mutils1' (/username/DeepFacade-master/mutils1.py)
```

Comment: Why are you pretending your code is HTML/JS, when it is not? Stackoverflow does support syntax highlighting for python.

Comment: The code of mutils.py is basically irrelevant. What's more important is how you import it.

Comment: @Sören sorry, I pasted the code in the wrong place! I am gonna import "progress_bar" function which is within mutils1.py

Comment: What is your current working directory when you do the import?

Comment: I think the error means it found the mutil1.py file, but can't find anything called progress_bar. Check you've saved the file. Also try renaming mutil1.py. You'll get a different error message if that's the mutil1.py file being used.

Comment: @Sören the current directory is : ~/scratch/amirabb/DeepFacDe-master/mutils.py

Comment: @pcoates thanks for your response! I just renamed mutils1.py and it works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-can-i-import-other-python-files)