# how to use external scripts from main python file

Tags: python

so have 2 python project file one is qr scanner and other is youtube downloader. adn both are in different python file

so i wanna create an main python file where i will list the both project name like:

1. Qr Scanner
2. YouTube Downloader
   Enter You Option:

So when the user input their option. the script will gonna run in background using another terminal...

i searched in internet i dont understand anything so i didnt tried anything else

i dont know how to do it and where to start it

Comment: You'd have to start by sharing any code to get any relevant answer, but it sounds like you just need to import both of those modules and call there main entry points.

Comment: i want to run all my script from an main.py file..... i dont know how to start it so i didnt do any coding

Comment: I think you'll want to start with [Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Using subprocess for this is not good idea. Not that it is unsafe in this case, but it spawns more processes than necessary. If you want to create a python module that uses two other python modules / packages you just import them and call their api's directly.

Comment: Here is a great answer on this topic. [How can I import other python files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749411/2081835)

Comment: i also want to see the code running on the background terminal....how to do it?

Comment: Just output from your python application. As soon as it starts running, you have access to stdout and stderr from your program, anything you output will go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is what you want. It allows you to make command line calls by passing arguments to `.run()` method.

For example, you can call the `ls` bash command to get a list of files in the current directory.

```
import subprocess as sp
out = sp.run("ls", capture_output=True)
print(out.sdtout)
```

Comment: can i use it to run my external project file from another python file?

Comment: If you can call your python file form the terminal, then you can also call it with the subprocess module. Something along the lines of sp.run("python my_file.py", capture_output=True). You'll can check the documentation to see how to pass cmd line arguments as well.