# How to import my own packages in several other Python scripts in a way that's shareable?

Tags: python

I want to use my Python "toolbox" - packages I've written myself - in several other packages (let's call them pkg1 and pkg2 in the example below).

**Here is what my work directory looks like:**

```
└── WORK
    ├── PythonToolBox
    │   └── Tool1
    │       └── module1.py 
    ├── Use1
    │   └── pkg1
    │       └── p1_script.py
    └── SomeSubdirectory
        └── Use2
            └── pkg2
                └── p2_script.py
```

Let's say I want to import module1.py, from the package Tool1, into p1_script.py and p2_script.py.

Because of the architecture of my directories shown above, I believe I would need to write the following bit of code in p1_script.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
path_root = Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(str(path_root))
            
import PythonToolBox.Tool1.module1 as mod1
```

and do the same in p2_script.py, except that I'd need to make the following modification to the snippet of code above : `Path(__file__).parents[2] --> Path(__file__).parents[3]`.

That works, but it makes it hard to share work with others : I'd need to copy module1 into pkg1 before sending it to someone else, and remove the snippet of code to write `import module1.py as mod1` instead.

Another option would be to copy module1.py into pkg1 and pkg2 at the beginning. However, this doesn't seem like a good option either, as that would create two different versions of module1: I might improve module1 as I'm working on pkg1, and now pkg2 won't benefit from these improvements.

**Is there a better solution to use that toolbox than the two I've listed above?**

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749411/9842129 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349998/9842129. You may want to look at "importlib" docs

Comment: @mrVerma : I've read through both of your links, and while they describe several methods of importing modules, I don't think any brings more functionality or simplicity to the method I describe which changes sys.path. In all the cases they describe, I believe you still need to specify path, whether absolute or relative, which makes sharing work with colleagues difficult.
My question is more about organization than import : I'm surprised that I can't find a "canonical" way of using my own packages as modules in several other scripts without copy-pasting them or having to write specific paths.