# Writing common Functions in a separate File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have few functions in Python that are used across 8 different applications. So, I'd like to create a common functions file with a separate class and use it in several application.

What is the best approach. Below is my sample code.

**common_func.py**

```
import time

class common_funcs(object):
    
    def func1(func):
        def ret_func(*args, **kwargs):
            statement (....)
            while True:
            odc = ****
            if odc == 100:
                statement (....)
                continue
            break
        return rsp
    return ret_func

    @func1
    def nda_cal(ar1, ar2):
        res = xxxx(ar1, ar2)
        return res
    
    def func3():
        statement 1.... 
        return xyz
    
    def func4():
        return abc
```

Now I'd like to import func4 of this class in the file `common_func.py` into other application's code.
How can I do it efficiently?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `func4` supposed to be a static method? You should write these functions as normal functions in a module named something like `common.py` if you simply want to group them under the same namespace.

Comment: There is no apparent reason for these functions to be part of a class. Just write them as discrete functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you could import the **common_func.py** code into another python file like below:

```
from common_func import common_funcs # First, import your python file
obj = common_funcs() # Then, instantiate the class containing func4
func4_Results = obj.func4()# Finally, call func4
```

Note that you may have to revise the import statement to match where your **common_func.py** file is located.

To your question - without having more information about your situation, its difficult to say which method of importing a python file would be the "*most efficient*".

However, the link below points to another thread which offers a few different ways to import a python file, which may help you in determining which method is the best for your situation:

[Stackoverflow - How do I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files)