# Import elements from multiple submodules

Tags: python, module, package

I have a python project with a package, where the tree looks like this:

```
my_package
├── __init__.py
├── A.py
└── B.py
```

I would like to call several objects from `A` and `B` at once (from different files in the same command), is something "like" this posible?:

```
from my_package import ( # or some other syntax of course
    A_object_1,
    A_object_2,
    B_object_1
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files)

Comment: @Gameplay no, my question is a bit more specific, is it possible to get objects from two different files with the same import command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. It would be quite confusing if it was actually. What is wrong with separate imports though?

Comment: @Gameplay my usecase is similar to this: imagine the package `geometry` that has the submodules `basicFigures` (i.e. `point`) and `complexFigures`  (i.e. `star`). It could be nice to import `point` and `star` together

Comment: "Not possible" is also an answer :)

Comment: Well let's wait, maybe someone else knows something I don't in that matter :) You can always use `__init__.py` to organize that and in your file just "have those names" imported already.