# VSCode "go to definition" uses wrong Python module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am importing a module `foo` found in the same directory as my importing Python script.

```
    src/proj
           \_ main.py
           |_ foo.py
```

However, there is a foo installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` as well.

When I try to use VSCode to jump to a method defined in `foo` ("go to definition", `F12`), nothing happens (because the system instance of `foo` does not have such a method).  If I hover over the import itself and *go to definition*, I end up in the system `foo` (which is a directory containing `__init__.py` and the rest of the module contents).

How can I force VSCode to use my `foo.py` for the "*go to definition/declaration/etc.*" actions instead of the system `foo`?  (I believe the correct Python interpreter is configured.)

I've tried adding `'.'` to `extraPaths` (Python), but that did not help.  I even tried adding `'.'` to the **beginning** of `sys.path`, which also did not seem to help.

Note that I am editing remotely via SSH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files)

Comment: @TomServo, there is nothing wrong with the way I'm importing `foo`, as far as I know.  The script runs correctly.  It is just that VSCode insists on resolving the module to the other instance of `foo`.

Comment: @TomServo the question is about getting **the IDE** to recognize the path, not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I was wrong in thinking that only `foo` was not resolving.  In fact, the other modules in the same directory were not resolving either.  In those cases, since there was no conflicting name in the system space, I could not "go to definition" for the `import bar` line at all.

Second, a solution that seems to work for me is to "Open Folder" instead of opening each file I'm working with.  If I open the folder, then VSCode can and does resolve the references correctly, including `foo`.  It does not get confused.  Rather, it opens my `foo` and not the system `foo`.