# How to import a module in Python unit test?

Tags: python, import, pytest

```
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo.py
├── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── utils.py
    └── test_module.py
```

I have the above directory structure for my Python package.

Within the `test_module.py` file, I need to import `tests/utils.py`. How should I import it so that I can run the test by using both

- `python tests/test_module.py`
- `pytest`
  from the root directory?

Currently, I imported `tests/utils.py` as follows in the `test_module.py` file:

```py
from utils import myfunction
```

Then, `pytest` will generate the following error:

```
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

If I change to:

```py
from .utils import myfunction
```

Then, `pytest` works fine, but `python tests/test_module.py` generates the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I properly import `utils.py` so that I can use in both ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you run test with `pytest` from root directory, `test_module.py` is launch as a python module, so relative import is allowed.
- When you run test with `python tests/test_module.py`, it is launch as script and relative import is not allowed. But python adds `{root directory}/tests` directory to `sys.path`. So you can import with:

  ```py
  from utils import myfunction
  ```

You can mix these 2 cases with:

```py
try:
    from .utils import myfunction
except ImportError
    from utils import myfunction
```

To avoid this `try` statement, another solution is to run the script with `python3 -m tests.test_module` from the root directory ([PEP 338](https://peps.python.org/pep-0338/)). In this case `test_module.py` is loaded as a module and the relative import `from .utils import myfunction` works fine.