# Why is a Python module not being found?

Tags: python

The source in hypothesis_test.py, I have:

```
from utils import collapse_contiguous_ranges, check_number_in_range
@given(st.lists(st.integers()))
def test_collapse_contiguous_ranges(range: list[int]):
    collapsed = collapse_contiguous_ranges(range)
    for i in range:
        assert check_number_in_range(i, collapsed)
    assert collapse_contiguous_ranges(range) == [range[0], range[-1]]
```

Here is my command and my error:

```
 python -u "/Users/pitosalas/mydev/public-131-samples/memsim/memsim/tests/hypothesis_test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pitosalas/mydev/public-131-samples/memsim/memsim/tests/hypothesis_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import collapse_contiguous_ranges, check_number_in_range
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

And here is my directory structure. I've been stuck here before in other apps. I always mess around and sometimes it starts working. What can I try next?

[image]

Comment: check this question, [how-do-i-import-other-python-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files) it should help

Comment: You probably want to run `python -m memsim.tests.hypothesis_test` from the upper `memsim` directory, and change the import to `from memsim.utils import ...` Then you will have a consistent `sys.path` that should work reliably.

Comment: `utils.py` is not in the same directory as `hypothesis_test.py`.  Can you say why you **expected** the import to work?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Python import src modules when running tests](/q/4761041/4518341). Especially see [Joooeey's answer](/a/73897219/4518341) for advice about "src".