# Import all classes in directory?

Tags: python

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python), but that's not quite what I want to do.

I want to import all the classes in all the files in a directory. Basically, I want to replace this:

```
from A import *
from B import *
from C import *
```

With something dynamic, so that I don't have keep editing my `__init__.py` every time I add another file.

---

The `glob` solution seems to be the equivalent of

```
import A
import B
import C
```

which is not the same at all.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: And what's wrong with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python/1057534#1057534 ?

Comment: @Ignacio: Last sentence. I've got about 15 models, and all of them need to be imported, always. Doesn't make sense for me to have to keep updating `__init__.py` when this can be done programatically.

Comment: @Ignacio: You're not making sense. Why? Less typing. Less error prone. Won't forget to update the file. Saves time. Do I really need to justify this?

Comment: So then you're not doing this for the purpose of having plugins?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @Mark: Absolutely less typing involved, but that doesn't mean it is less error prone.  In fact, in deference to AJ's comment, I think it is potentially more error prone.

Comment: @Ignacio: No, no plugins. It's not supposed to be something like where you drop a file in there to include a plugin. Everything is going to be built by me. I've got a whole bunch of classes and I've split them all into separate files. The framework needs to load them all on startup so it knows they exist, and it also makes it easy for me to work with them without having to import a dozen different things all the time.

Comment: @AJ/Greg: Maybe. But they're classes. They're unlikely to introduce subtle bugs unless they're executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do something like this, although keep in mind `isinstance(cls, type)` only works with new-style classes.

```
import os, sys

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

for py in [f[:-3] for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.py') and f != '__init__.py']:
    mod = __import__('.'.join([__name__, py]), fromlist=[py])
    classes = [getattr(mod, x) for x in dir(mod) if isinstance(getattr(mod, x), type)]
    for cls in classes:
        setattr(sys.modules[__name__], cls.__name__, cls)
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that answer, it doesn't work. It imports the modules, but not the classes. I'd have to access the file as `address.Address` whereas I need to be able access it with just `Address`. There's a difference.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.py')` instead of `os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/*.py"`.

Comment: @Mark Adjusted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hrm....close. This `'.'.join([pkg, py])` needs to go one more level up. i.e., I had to replace it with `'.'.join(['shipments', pkg, py])` because the root of my project is one level higher. Can't we get the absolute path of the module so this doesn't have to be hard-coded?

Comment: @Mark Yeah sure, should just use `__name__` anyways. Adjusted again, see if that works for ya.

Comment: For me, `ImportError: No module named ...` occurs at `mod = __import__('.'.join([__name__, py]), fromlist=[py])`.

Comment: @zeekay what's the purpose of `setattr(sys.modules[__name__], cls.__name__, cls)`?

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume your file structure is as follows:

```
/Foo
    A.py
    B.py
    C.py
```

To import all at once, you need to create the `__init__.py` file in the directory you'd like to import everything from, with following code inside:

```
__all__ = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

This is the file structure after those changes:

```
/Foo
    A.py
    B.py
    C.py
    __init__.py
```

Then, you can simply use:

```
from Foo import *
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the `__all__ = ['A', 'B', 'C']` in `__init__.py`? it seams like there should be a more automatic way of adding all .py files in the directory to `__all__`

Comment: btw today seems doesn't work anymore