# Python: import every module from a folder?

Tags: python, import, directory

What would be the best (read: cleanest) way to tell Python to import all modules from some folder?

I want to allow people to put their "mods" (modules) in a folder in my app which my code should check on each startup and import any module put there.

I also don't want an extra scope added to the imported stuff (not "myfolder.mymodule.something", but "something")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python)

Comment: Check a similar thread and its answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If transforming the folder itself in a module, through the use of a `__init__.py` file and using `from <foldername>  import *` suits you, you can iterate over the folder contents
with "os.listdir" or "glob.glob", and import each file ending in ".py" with the `__import__` built-in function:

```
import os
for name in os.listdir("plugins"):
    if name.endswith(".py"):
          #strip the extension
         module = name[:-3]
         # set the module name in the current global name space:
         globals()[module] = __import__(os.path.join("plugins", name)
```

The benefit of this approach is: it allows you to dynamically pass the module names to `__import__` - while the  ìmport statement  needs the module names to be hardcoded, and it allows you to check other things about the files - maybe size, or if they import certain required modules, before importing them.

Comment: This still works in Python3.6, but the last line is changed to:
`import importlib; importlib.import_module("plugins" + "." + module)`

Comment: Thanks - they have deprecated the use of filenames in `__import__`. The funcion still works as well, one just have to use "." there instead of `os.path.join`

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named

```
 __init__.py
```

inside the folder and import the folder name like this:

```
>>> from <folder_name> import * #Try to avoid importing everything when you can
>>> from <folder_name> import module1,module2,module3 #And so on
```

Comment: Well then as suggested in the answer linked add the folder in the os.path list and import what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try that project: https://gitlab.com/aurelien-lourot/importdir

With this module, you only need to write two lines to import all plugins from your directory and you don't need an extra `__init__.py` (or any other other extra file):

```
import importdir
importdir.do("plugins/", globals())
```