# PyQt4 has no submodules

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I installed PyQt4 using a file found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10/) (Python 2.7, 32-bit). When I `import PyQt4`, I don't get an error, but when I try `from PyQt4 import QtCore`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QtCore
```

When I try to list PyQt4's submodules (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863867/5116094)), the only module listed is PyQt4 itself. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @Matho Yes, I am.

Comment: I'm not quite a Windows user, but I was testing `PyQt` there and [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) `pip` installation package was working fine. Maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can check where PyQt4 is being imported from (e.g. `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4`):

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> PyQt4
<module 'PyQt4' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\__init__.pyc'>
```

and check if that directory contains the submodules (e.g. QtCore.pyd):

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore
<module 'PyQt4.QtCore' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd'>
```

FWIW, my group has been getting PyQt from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11/PyQt4-4.11-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.6-x32.exe