# List modules in namespace package

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package, inspect

I'm trying to get Python to list all modules in a namespace package.

I have the following file structure:

```
cwd
|--a
|  `--ns
|     |--__init__.py
|     `--amod.py
|--b
|  `--ns
|     |--__init__.py
|     `--bmod.py
`--c
   `--ns
      |--__init__.py
      `--cmod.py
```

Each `__init__.py` defines it's package as a namespace package by having the following line:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

The `amod` module contains a class `A`, `bmod` contains another class `B` and `cmod` contains the `C` class.

When having a clean environment the following happens:

```
>>> import inspect, sys, glob
>>> sys.path += glob.glob('*')
>>> import ns
>>> inspect.getmembers(ns, inspect.ismodule)
[]
```

As you can see, the modules are not listed.

Now when I import the modules manually and then call the inspect again:

```
>>> inspect.getmembers(ns, inspect.ismodule)
[('amod', <module 'ns.amod' from 'a/ns/amod.pyc'>), ('bmod', <module 'ns.bmod' from 'b/ns/bmod.pyc'>), ('cmod', <module 'ns.cmod' from 'c/ns/cmod.pyc'>)]
```

Now I'd like the `inspect` call to work without importing the modules manually, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: I found this response helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8556471/131120

Comment: The answer seems to be here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-namespace-packages