# Python: how to import from all modules in dir?

Tags: python, import, module

Dir structure:

```
main.py
my_modules/
   module1.py
   module2.py
```

module1.py:

```
class fooBar():
    ....
class pew_pew_FooBarr()
    ....
...
```

How can I add all classes from module* to main without prefixes (i.e. to use them like foo = fooBar(), not foo = my_modules.module1.fooBar()).

An obvious decision is to write in main.py something like this:

```
from my_modules.module1 import *
from my_modules.module2 import *
from my_modules.module3 import *
...
```

But I don't want to change main.py when I create new moduleN. Is there solution for that?

I do know it's not a good idea to import classes like this, but I'm still curious about that.

UPD: This question differs from this one [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python), because my problem is to load modules without namespaces.

Comment: Do you mean Dynamic Module import in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python ?

Comment: Dynamic module import is quite complex solution for this, I think.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the `my_modules` folder, add a `__init__.py` file to make it a proper package. In that file, you can inject the globals of each of those modules in the global scope of the `__init__.py` file, which makes them available as your module is imported (after you've also added the name of the global to the `__all__` variable):

```
__all__ = []

import pkgutil
import inspect

for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)

    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if name.startswith('__'):
            continue

        globals()[name] = value
        __all__.append(name)
```

Now, instead of doing:

```
from my_modules.class1 import Stuff
```

You can just do:

```
from my_modules import Stuff
```

Or to import everything into the global scope, which seems to be what you want to do:

```
from my_modules import *
```

The problem with this approach is classes overwrite one another, so if two modules provide `Foo`, you'll only be able to use the one that was imported last.

Comment: can the above code go in __init__.py file or should it go somewhere else so as to automatically import modules.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. However, `find_module` is deprecated since 3.3.

Comment: Thanks so much - I've been looking for a while for THIS portable (zip or module) way to import all modules in a package - this worked perfectly!

Comment: A simpler alternative to `loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)` is `importlib.import_module(name)`