# Python2.7: Import all modules from a directory in file in another directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

Directory structure:

```
/dir1
    foo.py
    bar.py
/dir2
    test.py
```

Now, I want to import all the modules present in `dir1` and use it in `test.py` present in `dir2`. I have used an `__init__.py` in `/dir1` with the following contents:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob

modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) if not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

However, when I do a `from dir1 import *` in `test.py`, it says `no module named dir1`.

I did come across quite a few similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852811/python-how-to-import-from-all-modules-in-dir), but nothing seemed to solve the problem.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if you want to from dir1 import * I think you have to edit the  __init__.py  in dir1

Comment: Yeah, i have done that. It's mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Python only searches in the current directory, and presumably you're running this from within `dir2` - therefore Python expects `dir1` inside of `dir2`.

You need to tell Python where to find `dir1`, and one way is to add this directory to the system path inside of `test.py`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/parent/of/dir1')
```

Comment: I did that, @Martin, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you add that to the `test.py` file?

Comment: Yeah. When i print `sys.path` from inside the `test.py` file, I can actually see  `'/path/to/parent/of/dir1'` present. However, it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you confirm, that `dir1` isn't actually in the path. That it ends precisely at the parent dir's name.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Martin. The mistake I'd made was I'd added the path to `dir1` and not to `parent of dir1`. :)
It's working now

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `importlib`

The following works in Python 3.3+ [See Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.machinery)

```
    from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

    path = '../dir1/foo.py'
    module_name = 'foo'

    loader = SourceFileLoader(module_name, path)
    module = loader.load_module()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution to python 2.7. I edited my question just now to make that clearer. :)

Comment: Check out this function in the Fabric code: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py#L135