# How do I load all modules under a subdirectory in Python?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module

I place my frequently used modules in a subdirectory `lib/` and expect to load all modules into `main.py` by: (refer to [Python: how to import from all modules in dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852811/python-how-to-import-from-all-modules-in-dir))

```
from lib import *
```

but encounter the issue `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. More specifically, in `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lib import * # cause: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
#from lib.DominatingSets import *   # it works

dominatingSets = DominatingSets()
```

The full exception traceback:

```
$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    dominatingSets = DominatingSets()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

---

The directories in a tree-like format.

```
$ tree -P '*.py' .
.
├── __init__.py
├── lib
│   ├── AnalyzeGraph.py
│   ├── AutoVivification.py
│   ├── DominatingSets.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Output.py
│   ├── PlotGraph.py
│   ├── ProcessDatasets.py
│   └── ReadGTFS.py
├── main.py
```

The contents of `lib/__init__.py` are as follows. (refer to [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python))

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob
modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not basename(f).startswith('__')] # exclude __init__.py
```

Comment: I don't see any error in the code you have posted. However, as `from lib import *` run the code of all files in `lib` folder, the error may come from a piece of code you didn't post here. Check the line number given by the error raised.

Comment: @loutre Thx. I updated the question, please check it.

Comment: What I mean is that the error may come from a piece of code in one of the /lib/*.py files. You said `from lib.DominatingSets import *` worked, but what for the others? (`AnalyzeGraph`, `AutoVivification` and so on...)

Comment: @loutre I have tested all modules, `from lib.module import module`. All of them work.

Comment: Name clash somewhere?

Comment: @Mbo42 each `*.py` contains one class with **the same name**. For instance, `DominatingSets.py` contains one class `class DominatingSets: ...`. Is it the reason?

Comment: Not by itself ..  If You're on linux,  `grep -r "modulename(" .` from the top dir for each module name ? See if you have a method with a name clash. If somewhere you go blah = AnalyzeGraph(stuff) it will hit the module name, not the class. Mmm might have to test for AnalyzeGraph.xxx to0.

Comment: Thought about what you said re: class names being the same as module names. That has to be a potential problem. remember that Python will use '.' as a seperator for directory paths when specifying a path to an object. You should probably follow the conventions and use all lower case for modeles, and begin class names with a capital. I bet that would solve it.

Comment: @Mbo42 I checked it. all class names are unique by `$ find lib/ -name "*.py" | xargs grep -R 'class ' | cut -f 2 -d ':' | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: @DanGetz The full exception traceback is jointed.

Comment: @DanGetz @Mbo42, it doesn't work even though I only create `main.py`, `lib/__init__.py` and `lib/DominatingSets.py` (a null class `class DominiatingSets: def __init__(self): pass`).

Comment: Have you tried with lib/dominatingsets.py ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This confusion happened, in part, because your module names are the same as the names of the classes you want to load from them. (At least, that's what makes it more confusing.) Your code does correctly load the modules that your classes are in. However, it doesn't load the classes out of those modules, and this is what you actually wanted to do.

Because your class `DominatingSets` is in the module `lib.DominatingSets`, its full path from root is `lib.DominatingSets.DominatingSets`.

```
from lib import *
```

in your case will do the same thing as

```
from lib import DominatingSets
from lib import AnalyzeGraph
# ...
```

However,

```
from lib import DominatingSets
```

is equivalent to

```
import lib.DominatingSets
DominatingSets = lib.DominatingSets
```

but `lib.DominatingSets` is a *module* (`lib/DominatingSets.py`), not the class you want.

```
from lib.DominatingSets import DominatingSets
```

is equivalent to

```
import lib.DominatingSets
DominatingSets = lib.DominatingSets.DominatingSets
```

which is why it works: this is the class you want imported into the name `DominatingSets`.

If you want to have `from lib import *` import all the classes in the submodules, you need to import these classes into the `lib` module. For example, in `lib/__init__.py`:

```
from DominatingSets import *
from AnalyzeGraph import *
# ...
```

While you're making changes, I'd suggest (as others have) using normal Python naming conventions, and have your module names in lowercase: change `DominatingSets.py` to `dominatingsets.py`. Then this code would become

```
from dominatingsets import *
from analyzegraph import *
# ...
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thx a lot.

Comment: thx for ur advice. Modules should have short, **all-lowercase** names, as described in [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code: Package and Module Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id35)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your Traceback, I think your problem might lie here:

Firstly, lets look at an example:

```
import datetime
d = datetime(2005, 23, 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Basically, we've just imported the entire `datetime` module, and we're trying to call it like a class object within a module. Let's now do:

```
k = datetime.datetime(2005, 12, 22)
print k
2005-12-22 00:00:00
```

No problems this time, as we are referencing the `datetime` object type within the datetime module

If we do:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Again we reach the desired object, as we are importing the `datetime` class within the `datetime` module.
Also, using `*`

```
from datetime import *
d = datetime(2005, 3, 12)
```

will also work, as you are importing all the classes within the `datetime` module.

Your code saying:

```
from lib import * # This imports all MODULES within lib, not the classes
#from lib.DominatingSets import *   # it works because you import the classes within the DominatingSets Module
```

You could either use `from lib.DominatingSets import DominatingSets` which should solve your problem, or if you stick to `from lib import *`, change your code to `dominatingsets = DominatingSets.DominatingSets()`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I learnt a lot from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35997247/595305) here ... but I still had problems with what to put in the lib/__init__.py file, if this directory lib is not actually included in PYTHONPATH.

I found that in addition to adding the parent directory of lib in the caller file, i.e.

```
sys.path.append( '.../parent_dir_of_lib' )
```

I either 1) had to do this *in addition* in the caller file:

```
sys.path.append( '.../parent_dir_of_lib/lib' )
```

Or 2) had to make the lib directory "self-loading", by putting this in its __init__.py:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
parent_dir_str = str( Path(__file__).resolve().parent )
sys.path.append( parent_dir_str )
 
from analyse_graph import *
from auto_vivification import *
...
```