# How to import some set of Python modules globally?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

In my particular setting, I have a set of python modules that include auxiliary functions used in many different other modules. I putted them into a LIBS folder and I have other folder at the same path level those are including other modules that are doing certain jobs by using the help of these LIBS modules. Presently, I do this for all the modules to import LIBS modules.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../LIBS')

import lib_module1
import lib_module2
....
```

As the project getting larger, this starts to be pain in the neck. I need to write down a large set of import statements for these auxiliary LIBS modules for each new module.

Is there any way to automatically import all these LIBS modules for the other modules that are in the folders living at the same path lelvel with LIBS folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as it has an extra step involved.  The answer may be based on that question, but this question doesn't assuming starting from __init__.py (which I just learned about due to this question).

Answer (score 4):

For this, you can use

```
 __init__.py
```

Kindly refer [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/1505987).

Comment: Nope, not required. You can just import all the required modules in \__init__.py.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is! Start treating your LIBS modules as "real" modules (or packages) that are installed into the system like any other.

This means you will have to write a `setup.py` script to install your code. Generally this is done inside your development directory, then your module is installed with:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

This will install your module under the `site-packages` subdirectory of wherever Python libraries are stored on your system.

I suggest starting by copying someone else's working `setup.py` and supporting files, then modifying to suit your packages. For example, here is [my quoter module](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/quoter/src).

Fair warning: This is a pretty big step. Not only will you learn to deploy your module locally, you can also publish it on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) if you wish. The step of moving to true packages will encourage you to write more and more standard documentation, to develop and run more tests, to adopt [more rigorous version specifications](http://semver.org), to more clearly identify and define code dependencies, and take many other "professionalization" steps. These all pay dividends in better, more reliable, more portable, more easily deployed code--but I'd be lying if I didn't admit the learning curve can be steep at times.