# Why doesn't "__all__" have desired effect for "import *"?

Tags: python

File structure:

```
./__init__.py
  a.py
    /lib
    __init__.py
    Foo1.py # contains `class Foo1`
    Foo2.py # contains `class Foo2`
    # so on ...
```

Tested this in `a.py` and worked, doing this;

```
from lib.Foo1 import Foo1
from lib.Foo2 import Foo2
```

But, when I do `from lib import *` the `__all__ = ["Foo1", "Foo2"]` in `__init__.py` it doesn't work.

Error: `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'module' object is not callable`

What I'm missing?

Here is `a.py`;

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

from lib import *

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print "Test!"

foo1 = Foo1()
foo2 = Foo2()
```

Used these refs:
    http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package
    [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057431/362780)

Answer (score 4):

```
from lib import *
```

Will import everything in `lib` to the current module, so our `globals()` looks like:

```
{'Foo1':<module lib.Foo1>,
 'Foo2':<module lib.Foo2>}
```

Whereas

```
from lib.Foo1 import *
from lib.Foo2 import *
```

Makes our `globals()` become

```
{'Foo1':<class lib.Foo1.Foo1>,
 'Foo2':<class lib.Foo2.Foo2>}
```

So in the first case we're just importing modules, not the classes inside them which is what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `.../lib/__init__.py` file:

```
from Foo1 import Foo1
from Foo2 import Foo1

__all__ = ['Foo1', 'Foo2']
```

Note that PEP-8 recommends that [package and modules names be all lowercase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

When importing `*` from a package (as in your case, using the `__all__` in `init.py`) `__all__` specifies all modules that shall be loaded and imported into the current namespace.

So, in your case, `from lib import *` will import the modules `Foo1` and `Foo2` and you need to access the classes like so:

```
foo1 = Foo1.Foo1()
foo2 = Foo2.Foo2()
```

Have a look at [Importing `*` in Python](http://shahriar.svbtle.com/importing-star-in-python) for a quick clarification.