# Importing python scripts not working

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a python script (graphics.py) into my other script (game.py), however, it's not working.

In game.py:

```
import pygame
import graphics.py
import sys # Mainly for sys.quit

"""********Start variables********"""

# Some colour constants
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

# Display settings
FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    pygame.init()

    # Load graphics
    gfx = graphics()
```

And in graphics.py:

```
import pygame

class graphics(object):

    # Create a surface that will hold the player sprite
    SprPlayer = pygame.Surface((32, 32))

    # At the beggining of the object, load the sprites
    def __init__():
        SprPlayer = pygame.image.load("Graphics\Player.png")
```

So I'm making my first python game, (Python is my new favorite language other than GML.) and I can't have everything in one file.
Here is the error

```
import graphics.py
ImportError: No module named py
```

I have both scripts in the same directory, so I don't know what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the tutorial told you to import modules that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you don't need to include the file extension when you are trying to import python modules, hence the `No module named py` because python is trying to import a file called `py` from a folder called `graphics`. What you want is just `import graphics`.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

In python, you do not need to add the '.py' extension on the end of a file from the same directory. Try `import graphics`. To learn more, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python/20753073#20753073) stackoverflow answer.