# Import * from all modules in a package in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I have a package whose structure is like this:

```
/backends/
    __init__.py
    abc.py
    def.py
    ghi.py
    xyz.py
    common.py
```

The modules `abc.py`, `def.py`, `ghi.py` and `xyz.py` contain some common functions e.g. `func0()` and `func1()`.

In the `common.py` module I am importing * from all modules like this:

```
from abc import *
from def import *
from ghi import *
from xyz import *
```

I don't think this is a *Pythonic* way to do this. Think about a few tens of such modules.

What I want is to have a single line statement which imports * from all the modules in the package. Something like this:

```
from backends import *
```

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python), but couldn't get what I wanted. I created a variable `__all__` in the `__init__.py` and assigned the list of all modules to it. The I put this import line in the `common.py` module:

```
from . import *
```

And then I tried to access the function `func0()` which is present in any module (except in `__init__.py` and `common.py`) in the package. But it raised an error which reads

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I need a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I tried myself and it worked,
I'll presume that you will be working with `common.py` as your main module where you'll be importing the rest modules in it, so:

1 - In the `__init__.py` file, add:

```
import os
import glob
modules = glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if os.path.basename(f)[:-3] != 'common']
```

2 - In `common.py` add:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
#print sys.path  #for debugging

import backends
#from backends import *   #up to you, but previous is better
```

Comment: I would reject this in a code review. All it takes is a `junk.py` file in the module directory to screw everything up.

Explicit is better than implicit. An `__all__` declaration with static names is explicit; scraping the directory for names is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Voila! Found a solution which I am completely satisfied with. :-)

I left the `__init__.py` module untouched. And instead put the following codes in the beginning of the `common.py` module.

```
import os

pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_names = os.listdir(pwd)

for name in file_names:
    if ".pyc" not in name and "__init__" not in name and "common" not in name and ".py" in name:
        exec "from "+name[:-3]+" import *"
```

It worked like charm. Though I don't know whether this is the best solution. I guess in Python 3.x, exec statement will be like following:

```
exec("from "+name[:-3]+" import *")
```