# import Python plugins from a folder

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

I want to put a python script with module script PIL on a server. The server might not have PIL installed. (This is why I want to load the file myself)

If possible, how can I have the python script import Image Library from the current directory of the script without having it installed on the machine?

---

Using python virtual machine
I am using v2.7 of python locally, as on server.

Comment: Why don't you use a virtualenv?
If you install a python module in the virtual env, it won't affect your Python distribution installed on the machine.

Comment: Someone jumped your gun by giving it as an answer. I should have mentioned that I have no Python experience.

Comment: Take a look here : 
[link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) 

It's really simple, it creates a virtual environnement in wich your can install all dependencies for your script to run without affecting the machine Python.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to import modules from a relative path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path).

It is also possible to use virtual environments where you pack everything you need and don´t mess with python installations on the server. Look it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and [here](http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2014/09/16/python_3_4_on_ubuntu_14_04_using_virtual_environments.html)

Other references:

1. [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python)
2. [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. +1 however I am mending my question to include the version. Servers usually come standard with 2.7. I need the script to support that version.