# Reload a whole package structure in Python

Tags: python, import, package, reload, maya

I'm working within Maya. What i need is to import a custom package and completely reload it inlcuding all subpackages and modules. Mainly because i want Maya autocompletes for me the module path while im writing. For example i have this kind of package structure

```
root (package)
    subpackage1 (package)
        __init__.py (module)
        a.py (module)
        b.py (module)

    subpackage2 (package)
        c.py (module)
        d.py (module)
        e.py (module)
```

What i did on **__init__.py** files is to import all submodules and one by one to reload them there

**ex: root.subpackage1.__init__.py**

```
import a
import b
reload(a)
reload(b)
```

This is very tedious, and thus i suppose there is a much better way to import and reload all the structure

When i import the package the first time the whole structure is load into memory.

```
import root
reload(root)
root.subpackage1.a.my_function()
```

so lets suppose now i update a.py file and add a function named my_test. I need again to reload all package structure to be able to evaluate it like this.

```
root.subpackage1.a.my_test()
```

whitout doing this...

```
from root.subpackage import a
reload(a)
a.my_test()
```

I wall everything to be reloaded when i import and reload **root**
whats the best practice to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Anyone who can point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I have found is directly based on this answer to a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/7124215). I have introduced some changes for the __init__.py files of your question:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob

modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]

from . import *
for module in __all__:
    reload(module)

del dirname, basename, isfile, glob, modules
```

Does this help? I apologize if I have not understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, its a nice way to reload all content dynamically.