# Why import by filename is not supported?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I want to import all python modules in a directory in python, and came across this snippet:

```
for name in os.listdir("modules"):
    if name.endswith(".py"):
        module = name[:-3]   # remove extension name for convenience.
        globals()[module] = __import__(os.path.join("modules", name))
```

program outputs:

`ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

How to I import file by filename?

Comment: To import all Python modules in a directory, use an `__init__.py` file. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python [duplicate]