# python -m cannot find my modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wrote a package, which lives in `/home/michael/python/mcdb-mail-parser/`

The file structure in there is:

```
 .
 ├── __init__.py
 ├── mcdb_mail_parser
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── MCDBAttachment.py
 │   ├── MCDBEmail.py
 │   ├── Options.py
 ├── mcdb-mail-parser.conf.sample
 ├── mcdb-mail-parser.py
 ├── README.md
```

`mcdb-mail-parser.py` imports from the `mcdb_mail_parser` subdirectory.

if I run the scripts from the source directory (`/home/michael/python/src/mcdb_mail_parser`) it works fine because the `mcdb_mail_parser` directory is immediately available in the current directory. However, I need to run it from the home directory of another user (via a cronjob, or from another script via subprocess), python complains it cannot find the module:

I tried to execute it with `python3 -m /home/michael/python/src/mcdb_mail_parser`, but it complains:

```
michael@d8:~$ python3 -m /home/michael/python/mcdb-mail-parser/
/usr/bin/python3: No module named /home/michael/python/mcdb-mail-parser/
```

I am not sure where to go from here. I think that it's a path issue. I could add `/home/michael/python/src/mcdb_mail_parser` to the system path, or perhaps python path, but that seems like the wrong solution. I certainly don't want to hard code paths into any scripts either.

How do I tell python: "Run the `mcdb-mail-parser.py` script from `/home/michael/python/src/mcdb_mail_parser` directory?

*Closing notes*
The accepted answer was useful, and so was the link they provided. Here's what I eventually did:
 1. I moved the contents of `mcdb_mail_parser` from the subdirectory into the same directory as `README.md`, thus removing one level of complexity.
 2. I added the import statements to `__init__.py` as suggested.
 3. Python complained it couldn't find `__main__.py`, so I renamed `mcdb-mail-parser.py` to `__main__.py`

Comment: `python -m` wouldn't work here anyway because there's no `__main__.py`. You could just leave the `-m` out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the modules in the `__init__.py` that's in the sub directory and then have the `Import` in `mcdb-mail-parser.py` reference that directory

Very similar to this previous StackOverflow Post ->
[Loading all modules in a folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python#1057534)