# Import all classes from all files from a package

Tags: python

I have a package with files, each file has a class:

```
model
 -- User.py
 -- Project.py
 -- Item.py
 -- __init__.py
```

inside `__init__.py` I have this:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob
modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

as explained inside this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/2337243

Now my problem is:

I can now use the imported classes in another class but only by doing this:

```
from model import * 
results = session.query( User.User).all()
```

My question is: how do I import the model classes and simply call the classes like this:

```
results = session.query( User).all()
```

N.B: each file inside model package has one single class that has the same name as the file name.

Comment: importing the classes inside the `__init__` file doesn't work? Basically, the following lines inside `__init__`: `from .User import User; from .Project import Project; from .Item import Item`?

Comment: Well yeah that's what I was looking for ! thanks

Comment: How do I automatically import all these classes ? Instead of having to type `from .User import User` manually?