# Python flask application throws the following error on start ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python, python-importlib

I've a flask application cloned from git after installing all of its requirements and starting the app by

$ python start.py

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app("local")
  File "C:\Jahangeer\qurbcode\api\app\__init__.py", line 66, in create_app
    from app.api_1_0 import apibp as api_1_0, api_spec as api_1_0_spec
  File "C:\Jahangeer\qurbcode\api\app\api_1_0\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    ModuleImport.importModulesFromPath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), __name__)
  File "C:\Jahangeer\qurbcode\api\app\helpers\module_import.py", line 16, in importModulesFromPath
    importlib.import_module("." + module, package)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Start.py have the following code

```
import os
from app import create_app

app = create_app("local")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

and Inside my **init**.py on line 66 which is mentioned in above error has the following

```
 # Setup api/1.0 blueprint
    from .api_1_0 import apibp as api_1_0, api_spec as api_1_0_spec
    from .admin import admin_bp as admin
    app.register_blueprint(api_1_0, url_prefix='/api/1.0')
```

Here is application structure

```
api
->admin_app
->app
  ->admin
  ->api_1_0
  ->__init__.py
->start.py
->manage.py
```

My api\app\helpers\module_import.py have the following code:

```
import glob
import importlib


class ModuleImport:

    @staticmethod
    def importModulesFromPath(dir_path, package, import_init = False):
        files = glob.glob(dir_path + "/*.py")
        for file in files:
            module = file.replace(dir_path, "").replace("/", "").replace(".py", "")

            if module == "__init__" and not import_init:
                continue

            importlib.import_module("." + module, package)
```

and my api\app\api_1_0__init__.py have the following code: on line 78

```
ModuleImport.importModulesFromPath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), __name__)
```

Comment: It looks like your problem's actually happening a bit lower down in your application. Could you also drop the context for `api\app\api_1_0\__init__.py` and `api\app\helpers\module_import.py`? It looks like you've got some kind of home-rolled module importing setup, and that's probably what's causing you issues.

Comment: @ymbirtt please review the edited question again. Posted code of both file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autoloader is almost certainly doing a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>.

It looks like your code is designed to be run on Linux, but you're running it on Windows. In and of itself, this isn't necessarily bad, but it's not written in a way that supports this. Specifically, `glob.glob(dir_path + "/*.py")` is returning you the paths to all the `.py` files in a directory, and they'll come out looking like `C:\\path\\to\\file.py`. Later, the chain `module = file.replace(dir_path, "").replace("/", "").replace(".py", "")` will try and strip the `.py` and the `C:\\path\\to` parts, leaving you with `\\file`, but `.replace('/', '')` won't remove that leading backslash, because it's looking for forward slashes and windows uses backslashes. You'll then attempt to import `\\file`, which you can't do because you can't pass a path to the `__import__` function - that's not how that works.

In the short term, you might find that everything springs into life if you change your `ModuleImport` tool to have an `import os` at the top. Then replace `dir_path + "/*.py"` with `os.path.join(dir_path, '*.py')`, and `replace("/", "")` with `replace(os.sep, "")`. This should fix your immediate problem, but you shouldn't leave the code like that.

Longer term, this is not a good way to autoload modules, and if you're screwing around with importlib to get your modules to load properly, you can probably load your modules in a far better way. I usually consider it a code smell when I see things like `sys.path.append` or `importlib.import` knocking around. You might find that your code is easier to maintain if you look at [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to hard code paths.

You can use `pathlib`, if you're using `Python 3`, or `os.path.join` otherwise.

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("source_data/text_files/")

file_to_open = data_folder / "raw_data.txt"

f = open(file_to_open)

print(f.read())
```

or even if you'd like to get the windows path:

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

filename = PureWindowsPath("source_data\\text_files\\raw_data.txt")

correct_path = Path(filename)

print(correct_path)
# "source_data/text_files/raw_data.txt" on Mac and Linux
# "source_data\text_files\raw_data.txt" on Windows
```