# Load Plugins at runtime

Tags: python, plugins, python-import

I have a directory called `plugins`. It contains an empty `__init__.py` file.

There can be several Python files in this directory. For example `plugin_a.py` and `plugin_b.py`.

I want to import these files at runtime.

How to import all files in the `plugins` directory?

I want to leave the `__init__.py` file empty.

The existence of a new file in the directory should be enough to make the plugin available.

This loading happens in a script. At runtime no new python files get added. Loading once is enough.

Comment: Where are you importing the plugin from? A long-running process or a script? Do you need to hot-reload? Or import at startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)