# Importing functions in .py files and using them by calling function_name

Tags: module, python-import

I have a folder called `Script_py`, and containing a lot of .py files, for example `tri_insertion.py` and `tri_rapide.py`.

Each `name.py` contains just one function called also `name`. My aim is to :

- import all the functions (and if I have to add an other .py file, it will be imported automatically),
- execute one function with the command 'name(parameters)'.

I tried the solutions of [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder) with a dynamic `___all___` in `___init___.py`, and `from Script_py import all`, but a calling to a function is `name.name(parameters)` instead of `name(parameters)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally the following solution works fine. Fristly, I store in a list the complete list of modules :

```
import os, pkgutil
test = list(module for _, module, _ in 
            pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname('absolute_path')]))
```

Secondly, I import all the modules with a for loop.

```
for script in test:
    exec("from {module} import *".format(module=script))
```