# Dynamically initialize Frames in a folder in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to import all the Frames I have inside a folder as a package and then initialize all those frames so I can just `raise` them on a button press.

This is my folder structure:

```
+-projectfolder
|--bargraphtutor.py
|-- __init__.py (empty)
|--pages
   |--startpage.py
   |-- .
   |-- .
   |--aboutpage.py
   |--__init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` in the `pages` folder has the following code to package all the `.py` files in that folder into `pages`. That was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder).

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob

pages = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in pages if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
from . import *
```

And then I get to do `import pages as p`. The issue is that, each frame is a class in the file and to initialize each frame I have to know the name of each file and class name:

Example: Part of bargraphtutor.py

```
self.frames = {}
for F in (p.aboutpage.AboutPage, p.startpage.StartPage): # This is where I'd like to make as 
    page_name = F.__name__                               # automated as possible. 
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
    self.frames[page_name] = frame

    # put all of the pages in the same location;
    # the one on the top of the stacking order
    # will be the one that is visible.
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Example: startpage.py:

```
import tkinter as tk   # python 3
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Button
from tkinter import font


class StartPage(tk.Frame):   # Each Frame is defined via a class

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        titleLabel= ttk.Label(self, text='This is the Startpage')
        titleLabel.pack()
```

So how can I import the package and then iterate over all the Frames in bargraphtutor.py but without knowing all the class names? I got as far as using `p.__all__` which returns the names of all the files in the package but I don't know how to move forward from there.

Edit: If I named the file the same as the class, would I run into problems with namespaces?

Comment: The simplest would be you name all your `class <Page>(...` same as your `module` file name.Then you can do: `for F in <__all__>:`. Note the `<...>` are placeholders.

Comment: @stovfl I was thinking about that but I wasn't sure if would cause some kind of conflict with namespaces? Even if I named the class the same name as the file, wouldn't I still have to do <filename>.<classname> ?

Comment: ***"problems with namespaces?"***: No, it's common used. For example, `from dateteim import datetime`. The module filename is `datetime.py` and inside a `class datetime`.

Comment: @stovfl okay I understand. Won't I still have to use `<package>.<filename>.<classname>` though? Or will naming the classes the same as the filename allow for `<package>.<classname>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Dynamically initialize Frames in a folder in Tkinter

### Core Point

Get the `module` from `pages.__init__`, then get the page `class`.

```
cls = getattr(getattr(pages, module_name), page_name)
```

---

### Reference

> - [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)
>     Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string

---

**Note**: I don't pass a `controller` reference as it's the same as `class App`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import pages


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("200x200")

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.configure(menu=menubar)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.pages = {}
        for filename in pages.__all__:
            module_name, page_name = filename, filename
            cls = getattr(getattr(pages, module_name), page_name)

            self.pages[page_name] = frame = cls(self)

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            menubar.add_command(label=page_name, command=frame.tkraise)

        # The following statements are equivalent 
        self.pages['StartPage'].tkraise()

        # From within a page object
        # self.master.pages['StartPage'].tkraise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

The way I would solve this is to have all of my pages inherit from a base class so that I could use the [__subclasses__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__subclasses__#class.__subclasses__) function to get a list of all subclasses once they've been imported. To import them I would use python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to find the files and the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module to import the files by their paths.

### Example file structure

For example, let's start with this simple folder structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── pages
    ├── PageOne.py
    ├── PageTwo.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── basepage.py
```

**__init__.py** is empty, but lets us treat `pages` as a module.

**basepage.py** defines the class `BasePage`, from which all other pages inherit from. It doesn't need to be much, since each page will be responsible for everything inside the page. It might look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class BasePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        self.master = master
        self.controller = controller
        super().__init__(master)
```

**PageOne.py** and **PageTwo.py** contain the pages. They have a similar structure. For example, **PageOne.py** might look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from .basepage import BasePage

class PageOne(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one")
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
```

Page two is identical, except it says "two" instead of "one" in the obvious places. Notice how this page inherits from `BasePage`. This is important, as you'll see in a minute.

### Getting a list of files to import

You can use the `glob` module to get a list of all files in the "pages" subdirectory. It would look something like this:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("./pages/*.py"):
    ...
```

If your actual folder has files that are pages and files that are not, you can use a naming convention so that you only import page files. For example, you could change the pattern to `".pages/Page*.py"`.

### Importing a file by its filename

Python's [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module has functions which allow us to import files by filename.

For example, given a filename in `filename`, we can import that file like this:

```
import importlib.util
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(filename)
module_name = f"pages.{path.stem}"
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, path)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

If we pass in something like `./pages/PageOne.py` it will load the module under the name `pages.PageOne`.

### Getting the page classes

Once we've imported one or more pages, here's where we use the `BasePage` class. Remember how every page inherits from this class? We can use the [__subclasses__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__subclasses__#class.__subclasses__) method of a subclass to give us a list of all subclasses.

Putting that all together, here's a function that imports all files matching "Page*.py" in the "pages" subfolder and then returns the classes:

```
def get_pages(self):
    for filename in glob.glob("./pages/*.py"):
        path = Path(filename)
        module_name = f"pages.{path.stem}"
        print(f"module name: {module_name}")
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, path)
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    return BasePage.__subclasses__()
```

### Creating the page instances

At this point, creating the page instances is pretty easy. Your main program could do something like this:

```
    self.frames = {}
    for page_class in self.get_pages():
        page = page_class(parent=page_container, controller=self)
        page_name = page_class.__name__
        self.frames[page_name] = page
        page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation! Just one thing, isn't using `exec` considered bad practice?

Comment: @S.Ramjit: this example doesn't use `exec`. At least, not in the way you're thinking of it. You're asking about the built-in function [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec), but this code uses the [exec_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.exec_module) method of the loader object. They are two different functions. And yes, the built-in `exec` method should be avoided. However, "avoided" isn't the same as "never use". There are right ways and wrong ways to use both of these functions.