# Cannot Import * from a Subdirectory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to import a set of modules from a subdirectory into a single main module in the parent directory:

Project/

```
main.py
subdirectory/
    __init__.py
    timer.py
    example.py
```

I can ask for any of the individual .py files like so:

```
from subdirectory import timer.py
```

But, if I run the following command,

```
from subdirectory import *
```

and I try to use a module within that subdirectory, I get the following error:

```
File "My:\Path\Here\...", line 33, in main
t = timer.timer()
NameError: name 'timer' is not defined
```

I want to be able to import all of the files in one batch, as I am importing a couple of modules. I already added a blank **init**.py file to the subdirectory.
Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare your module names using `__all__` in your `__init__.py`:

`__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ["timer", "example"]
```

This behaviour is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The `import` statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The import * statement works properly now, and I can use the modules that I imported.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just make the imports work, then add `subdirectory/__init__.py` with the following content:

```
from * import example
from * import timer
```

However, if you want to do this to an arbitrary number of (old and new) modules, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/604048) might be what you are looking for:

You start with the following structure:

```
main.py
subdirectory/
subdirectory/__init__.py
subdirectory/example.py
subdirectory/timer.py
```

Then import everything in `subdirectory` from `main.py`:

```
from subdirectory import *
t = timer.timer()
```

Then add the following to the `subdirectory/__init__.py` module:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not 
f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

And for completeness sake the `subdirectory/timer.py` module:

```
def timer():
    return 42
```

Comment: `from * import example` is a syntax error. I think you want `from . import example`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  That source did have good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Imports go like this.

```
# if you have timer.py, import it as 
import timer
```

Try adding `__init__.py` to the subdirectory.
It will now look like:

Project/

```
    main.py
    subdirectory/
                 __init__.py
                 timer.py
                 example.py
```

If that does not work:
in `main.py` add

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/subdirectory") # replace with the path
import timer
```

Comment: I have already done that.