# Import all modules from folder, execute function from all of them with known name

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Well, I have pretty hard task and I'm completely stucked, like in any direction.

What program should do:

1. Import all modules (names are random) from folder

> ```
>   MainScript.py
>   modules/
>       mod1.py
>       mod2.py
>       mod3.py
>       ...
> ```

2. Execute specific (known name, and everywhere it's same) function.

> mod1.main()
> mod2.main()
> mod3.main()
> ...

As I understand it, I should list all files in folder , then make list with them and for each [x] in list import module and execute script. I've found that `modules[0].main()` works only if `modules[0]` no string, so, it should be `modules[0]=main` not `modules[0]='main'`. So and there I need somehow deal with it...  but for `import` I don't know...

I've already googled about it, only found https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/10289135
And I guess it will not work for me (I also don't understand how it works and script didn't work for me)

Any ideas?

Comment: add what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

from filename(remove the .py) import *

This is a wild card import it imports every thing from a module literally everything .By doing this you dont need to do the work like 'filename.blabla' ,but simply you can do 'blabla'.

Comment: You completely misunderstand me

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
import sys
import importlib
modules = []
for i in os.listdir("C:\\Windows\\path\\to\\your\\modules\\"):
    mod = i
    modules.append(mod)
sys.path.append("C:\\Windows\\path\\to\\your\\modules\\")
for i in modules:
    i = i[:i.find(".")]
    module = importlib.import_module(f"{i}")
    module.main()
```

Comment: Gives error.

`    module.main()`
`AttributeError: module 'arp' has no attribute 'main'`

arp.py

`def main():
    print('arp')`