# Flask-migrate does not recognize all modules within a package?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, project-structure, flask-migrate

I'm new with flask-migrate (and so with Python...) but I'll get to the point.

I used to store all of my models inside a single `models.py` file but then I decided to separate every model to its corresponding file.

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder). I assumed this would be a quick way for Flask-Migrate (or Alembric) to know all modules within the models package. So I did that way, but once I tried the `flask db migrate` command, the generated migration file simply dropped a few tables but not all of them.

Here's the project structure:

```
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── api/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models/
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── model1.py
│       │   └── model2.py
│       ├── resources/
│       └── schemas/
└── run.py
```

**run.py**

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
app.run(port=5000)
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    # importing the models...
    from .api import models # this should work?
    # ... or do I have to manually write every single module?

    return app
```

**app/api/models/__init__.py**

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob

# Trying to apply what I learned from the referenced question...
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [
    basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith("__init__.py")
]
```

**Model files in app/api/models/**

```
from app import db

class ExampleModel(db.Model):
    # Model declarations goes here...
    pass
```

So... to summarize this question, **is there a better way to do this or I should import every single module in the `app/__init__.py` file?**

Comment: The `models/__init__.py` isn't importing any models, it just puts their names in `__all__`. I think all that's missing in your solution is actually importing the model classes in that file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You're right, I missed importing the rest of the modules inside the `models/__init__.py` file. All I needed was a simple `from . import *`.