# python import on all files

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, sys.path

```
App
ㄴCore
  ㄴ Controllers
     ㄴ working.py
     ㄴ Components
        ㄴ Elements
            ㄴAA.py
            ㄴAB.py
              (...)
            ㄴZZ.py
  ㄴ DTO
     ㄴH.py
     ㄴI.py
     ㄴk.py

ㄴConfig
 ㄴE.py
 ㄴF.py
ㄴDB
  ㄴdb.py
ㄴUtil
  ㄴutils.py
```

In the elements folder, import Config folder's python file and its classes
utils.py imported on most of all files.
In elements folder, there are many python files.
And, most of python files need to import classes in same directory's files.
And, most of python files need to import classes in DTO folders.
the python files in elements folder is imported hierarchically.

On my computer, it is not possible to register `sys.path(app_directory)`
When I tried to import AA to AB

`from AA import aa`
This is not working.

So, I added `__init__` in the components folder. And, importing AA to ZZ using `__import__`.
Then `from AA import aa` is working.
But, although I added app directory using `sys.path.append` on `__init__`, for instances, `from app.DB.db import db`, `from core.DTO.H import h`, `from DTO.H import h`, `from H import h`, `from . import h` is not working at python files in Elements folder.

I want to import necessary python files and classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)

Comment: @Xiddoc __init__ file in Controllers folder, I did  How to load all modules in a folder? solution already, but in this case, the path for DTO or Config or DB folder is not found, so I can't import it.