# Import files that are not known before the execution (Python)

Tags: python, import, subclass

In my project I have a generic class named Interface and many subclasses which inherit from Interface:

- /interface_folder/

  - interface.py
  - interface_a.py
  - interface_b.py
  - interface_c.py
  - ...
- /test/

  - test.py

The Interface class has a method which lists all the available methods of all its subclasses : their names, docstring, input and output arguments. I did this using the inspect module on Interface.`__subclasses__()`.

In test.py, if I want the Interface method using `__subclasses__()` to work, I need to import interface_a.py, interface_b.py, interface_c.py, etc.

I would like to automate these imports, so that I can add as many interface_x.py as I want in the folder without having to think of adding every time "from interface_folder.interface_d import Interface_d" at the beginning of test.py.

Is this possible?
If not, is there a solution to force python to build the `__subclasses__()`?

Comment: This scenario sounds a bit strange. Why do you need so many subclasses in the first place?

Comment: The reason is specific to my project : we allow the users to add their own subclasses to the "interface_folder" (one subclass per file) and the rest of the code is made to handle as many subclasses as needed. But right now only the import issue cannot be automatized

Comment: Well, I guess you could scan the folder for the relevant filenames, and then use `importlib.import_module()`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm with importlib.import_module() !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

- Create a new subfolder, say */interface_folder/child_interfrace_folder/*.
- Move all *interface_x.py* in the new subfolder.
- Import all files of the new subdirectory in *interface.py*. To do this:

  1. Create an *__init__.py* file in the new subdirectory and open it in your editor.
  2. In the new *__init__.py* file, list all *interface_x.py* files and put them in a variable named __all__. Example:

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder):

```
#  __init__.py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

You can now use `from child_interfrace_folder import *` in your *interface.py* file.