# Error importing files from a sub directory in python

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, subdirectory

I have made a small programming language and seperated the Lexer, Parser, and Interpreter into different files. Now I would like those files to be in a sub directory Source. I have Shell.py that uses them. In short, this is the structure.

```
Language -{
   Source -{
       Main.py
       Lexer.py
       Parser.py
       Interpréter.py
   Shell.py
```

In shell .py, I want to import main.py, which in turn imports the Lexer, parser, and interpreter.

So:

```
#Shell.py
import Source.Main
Main.run(some code)

#Main.py
from Lexer import Lexer
.... Parser
.... Interpreter
```

When I run Main.py everything works, but when I run Shell.py it comes up with this:

```
File Source/Main.py, line 1 in <module>
    from Lexer import Lexer
ImportError: No module named ‘Lexer’
```

EDIT:
There is an _*init_*.py in the Source directory.
I am not trying to import multiple files from the sub directory, just one that procedes to import others.

Comment: you probably need an `__init__.py` and it also depends on your current working directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Importing a file does not automatically import all the packages you imported in the file. Basically, when you imported Main.py, you didn't import the packages that Main.py imports. You need to manually import all of the packages in that folder.

EDIT: Based on a discussion in the comments, you need to change `import omega` to `from Source import omega` assuming Source is what you called the folder where your other files is stored.

Comment: Doing from source import * and the omega.run(some code) comes up with saying name ’omega’ is not defined

Comment: What is omega.run supposed to do? Where in your files is it defined? Depending on that, it could be being caused by a different problem

Comment: My bad, the example I am using uses different names than the original code. ”omega” is supposed to be main

Comment: ptierno's solution in the comments on your original post should work for you in that case.

Comment: I tried ptierno’s solution, but in the Lexer.py I have it importing Errors.py, with the same error popping up

Comment: That's because again, just because you imported a package, does not mean all the packages that the package imported imports are imported into your code,
Yes I know that that's a mouthful.

Comment: If you want to use errors.py without importing it into shell.py, inside your lexer.py make a function that uses the module, then use that function in your shell.py.

Comment: What I don’t understand is that Errors.py is in the same directory as Lexer.py, in Source. Also, Lexer.py would be the file that uses it, not Shell

Comment: Do you have a github repo or something I could take a look at?

Comment: https://github.com/Game1306/OMEGA  is the whole code

Comment: Check my post, I made an edit that you could try to use.

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. I also tried from Source import * with  the same error as well. In shell.py

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what to do then.