# Dynamic modules import with CLI runability - How to prevent duplicate load?

Tags: python, python-import

Assuming the following sample project structure:

```
src/
  animals/
    __init__.py
    cat.py
    dog.py
  zoo.py
```

I want to achieve the following two behaviors:

1. `animals` package dynamically imports all of its modules. This is required for the code that uses this package (say from `zoo.py`). This can be done in a fashion described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder). For example like this:

   ```
   # animals/__init__.py
   from pathlib import Path
   from importlib import import_module

   for f in Path(__file__).parent.glob("*.py"):
       if f.name == '__init__.py':
           continue
       import_module(f".{f.parts[-1][-3]}", __name__)
   ```
2. Each of the modules in `animals` should be separately runnable from CLI, for example like this:

   ```
   python3 -m src.animals.dog  # Runs some dog specific stuff, e.g. tests
   ```

So far, I fail to combine these two requirements together. The problem arises from the fact that this command line first loads the `animals` package which in turn imports `dog` among the other sub-modules. But later `dog` is being imported for a second time as `__main__`. This leads to a duplicate import (`dog` code being processed twice). I also get the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: 'src.animals.dog' found in sys.modules after import of package 'src.animals', but prior to execution of 'src.animals.dog'; this may result in unpredictable behavior.

One possible way I thought of solving it is somehow detecting which module is being invoked from the command line and skip its loading in `__init__`. But how do I find this info? Tried parsing `sys.modules['__main__']` but it seems mostly uninitialized.

Note: In the real project I have one more hierarchy level under `animals`, and I load all the sub packages, but that shouldn't matter for the sake of this example.