# Global variables and global statement from other modules

Tags: python, global, python-module

I came across some weird behaviour about how Python handles global (module) variables and the `global` keyword.

Module 1:

```
g = None

def set_g_up():
    global g
    g = "foo"

set_g_up()
print g
```

Module 2:

```
from module_1 import *

set_g_up()
print g
```

Module 1 prints, as expected, `"foo"`.
Module 2 prints `None`!

What? It’s the same object! Or, at least, I expect it to be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sharing global variables between modules and classes therein](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338283/python-sharing-global-variables-between-modules-and-classes-therein)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module has its own *global* name scope.  By importing everything via `*` from another module, you create *copies* (additional references to the values) of the globals of the other module into your own module.

Use qualified names in order to prevent this from happening:

```
import module_1

module_1.set_g_up()
print module_1.g
```

There is no way to access the same variable by calling it `g` if you in fact mean the variable `module_1.g`.  All you can make happen is that both variables contain the *same* value (makes only sense for lists, objects and other mutables).

Comment: One more reason for immutability. I now understand Rick Hickey.