# Changing value and importing - Doesn't save new value

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using latest python version; I have a simple function in one file, then another file calls that function. Problem is the variable from function isn't printed.

`file1.py`:

```
var = "one"
def first():
    global var
    if smt == True:
        var = "1"
    else:
        var = "W"
```

`file2.py`:

```
from file1 import *
first()
print(var)
```

This is simplified version because I have more irrelevant code, but the problem is still the same, my variable doesn't change for some reason.

Comment: You miss a tab before `global` and you should avoir the syntax `if smt == True` and just use `if smt`

Comment: This seems an interesting problem. Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of using `import *` is usually discouraged; due to the fact that it might be prone to namespace collisions, inefficient if the import is huge et cetera.

I would personally go for an explicit import: `from file1 import first`

I also believe that you have the wrong idea of what `global` is. This might help:

> In the first case the global keyword is pointless, so that is not
>   correct. Defining a variable on the module level makes it a global
>   variable, you don't need to global keyword.
>
> The second example is correct usage.
>
> However, the most common usage for global variables are without using
>   the global keyword anywhere. The global keyword is needed only if you
>   want to reassign the global variables in the function/method.

Keep in mind that you do *not* have `var` in `file2.py` by simply using `global` keyword; if you'd like to access the variable `var` you can use something like:

In `file1.py`:

```
var = "one"


def first():
    global var

    var = "1"
```

In `file2.py`:

```
import file1 

file1.first()
print(file1.var)
```

Comment: I tired that but then i get undefined variable if i want to use the one that was used in my function.

Comment: Answer updated; a global variable, is not shared across packages. - You need to use the example shown in my answer.

Comment: One funny thing was when I used `id()` on `var` in both files I got the same value. I cannot understand why. Thanks for this ans, I learned something. A related qn is https://stackoverflow.com/q/3338283/6561141

Comment: I get "Statement seems to have no effect" for file1.var

Comment: @tpk do you mind sharing how you used `id()`; as in on which variable; since you don't have `var` in `file1` unless you import the file and reference the variable; which in that case would be the same instance of the variable.

Comment: @webnub I updated the answer. - Try it again, although that warning comes from IntelliJ as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks, this works now. I tried to use var in file2 but kept getting undefined value and your last edit showed me why: i tried to use "var" when i needed to use "file1.var" when using it from that point :D

Comment: Glad it helped buddy.

Comment: @JulianCamilleri I was using `id()` on `var` in file1 and file2. I imported just as in the question.

Comment: They're not the same, if you try a small experiment: `id(var)` and `id(file1.var)` you'll see that both of which have different object identities.