# Reasoning behind `from ... import ...` syntax in Python

Tags: python, syntax, import

I always wondered why the syntax for importing specific objects from a module is `from module import x, y, z` instead of `import x, y, z from module`. I'm not a native speaker, but isn't the latter more correct/natural?

So, what is the reason to put the from first? Is it merely to simplify the grammar (require less lookahead)? Is it an attempt to make the two kinds of imports visually more distinct? Or is it one of these cases where the obvious way is "not obvious at first unless you're Dutch"? ;)

Comment: I'm still learning Python, but IMHO the following seems like it would have been more consistent with the rest of the language: `import(module, x, y, z)`. No need for `from` at all.

Comment: @FM: If you don't want `import` to get special syntactic treatment, you'd have to write `import('module', 'x', 'y', 'z')`, passing the *names* of the objects, because the objects themselves are unavailable until *after* the `import`.

Comment: The best import syntax I've ever seen was in Haskell: `import module (a, b, c)`. Clean, clear and makes multiple import statements look uniform and aligned (except for `import qualified` case, unfortunately). And I have no idea why GvR has chosen that ugly `from ... import`.

Comment: Starting a sentence with a preposition is neither ungrammatical or all that uncommon.  For example, "From Medford take Interstate 5 south." It all depends on what makes the sentence parse better. For many situations, including this one, it makes more sense to give context before action.

Comment: Related post - [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/710551/465053) & ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403/236257)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No idea why it was *actually* done that way but it's the way I'd do it, simply because, being an engineering type, it seems more natural to me to start from a general category and drill down to specifics.

It would also mean the parser would have to store less stuff if processing sequentially. With:

```
import x, y, z from a
```

you have to remember `x`, `y` and `z`. With:

```
from a import x, y, z
```

you only have to remember `a`.

---

That's why I had so much trouble when I first encountered Perl's post-if variant:

```
$x = $y if $y > 40;
```

since you don't know *in advance* whether what you're reading is conditional or not.

Comment: Now that you mention "postfix if", I think I see a readability bonus... +1, will be accepted unless uber-answer bei A.M. comes along ;)

Comment: So, nearly a decade later, I'll just add that now that we have better IDEs for python, the syntax `from foo import ba<ctrl+space>` allows for completion to be implemented by the IDE (providing options `bar`, `bat,`, `baz`...), since it knows from whence you're importing before you attempt the completion.

Answer (score 17):

A very wild guess and probably totally non-sense, but I knew that syntax from [Modula-2](http://www.modula2.org/reference/modules.php) (man, that was twenty years ago, I feel old)... maybe Python was inspired by it ?

Comment: Simplest answer, and most likely correct.  GvR took constructs from various languages in designing Python, including Modula-2, and this is probably a direct lift from that language.

Comment: Modula-2???? I feel your pain!!! Had to use it as our language of choice for the programming I and II (first year Computer engineering)... also 20 years ago. And the language was ancient already, I used a DOSbox :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the complete heritage of this syntax, as it dates from Python 1.x days.  But I find it useful to be able to scan down the left side of the source, and quickly find the module names that a script depends on.  If a statement read "import a,b,c,d,e,really_long_name, alsdf,lsdf from blah", it would take me a while to find that this script depended on blah.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from asking Guido directly, I don't think your going to find any explanation of this.

The syntax has been around from the very beginning.  The earliest version of python sources I could find was python 1.0.1.  Looking at the changelog in the Grammar file we find references to even earlier versions.  In version 2 of Python (I think we're talking 2nd release after 0.9.0) we have this note:

```
#   added 'from' NAME option on import clause, and '*' to import all;
```

This was added at the same time as

```
#   added class definition.
```

So the import statement sprang forth at the same time as classes were added to Python.  This comes from when Python was Guido van Rossum's solo project.  In other words, the answer you are looking for is lost in the sands of time.

Now, here's my speculation why the import statement reads `from x import y` rather than `import y from x`.

The [documentation for the import statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) provides the basic algorithm for implementing import:

> Import statements are executed in two
>   steps: (1) find a module, and
>   initialize it if necessary; (2) define
>   a name or names in the local namespace
>   (of the scope where the import
>   statement occurs). The statement comes
>   in two forms differing on whether it
>   uses the from keyword. The first form
>   (without from) repeats these steps for
>   each identifier in the list. The form
>   with from performs step (1) once, and
>   then performs step (2) repeatedly.

In both versions of the import statement the first step of this algorithm are leftmost.  I assume that this was the most obvious ordering for a language implementer, even though English might read more naturally if the order were reversed.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's not that strange. Look at how we "import", "include" or "require" in other languages. We always specify the namespace first. include "inc/config.php" in PHP for example. So in a way, it keeps our usual way of including files or modules.

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense in english to say `import x, y, z from module` but in programming it makes much more sense to bring the more general Item first and then bring the details.
It might not be the reason but it makes things easier for the compiler or interpreter.
Try writing a compiler and you'll know what I mean :D

Comment: I fully realize the difference for the compiler writer, but if I *as a programmer* cared about that, I'd stick to assembly with mnemonics :D

Comment: Not only for the compiler writer, It also helps IDEs to give you option, if you where to first write 'import' the IDE couldn't give you you any option because it didn't know from what module you want to import

Comment: Good point.  It reminds me of the SQL statement `SELECT Columns FROM Table` which suffers from that very problem with auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the programming language syntax you use. It is easier for me to read a such import.

İs it easier to read and understand

```
From Grocery buy apple and orange
```

or

```
Buy apple and orange from grocery.
Buy apple and orange from supermarket
```

First one suits me better...

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import:

`import foo                 # foo imported and bound locally
    import foo.bar.baz         # foo.bar.baz imported, foo bound locally
    import foo.bar.baz as fbb  # foo.bar.baz imported and bound as fbb
    from foo.bar import baz    # foo.bar.baz imported and bound as baz
    from foo import attr       # foo imported and foo.attr bound as attr`

I conclude it's a matter of local availability/binding.