# Unable to import a module that is definitely installed

Tags: python, importerror, python-module

After installing [mechanize](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/), I don't seem to be able to import it.

I have tried installing from pip, easy_install, and via `python setup.py install` from this repo: https://github.com/abielr/mechanize. All of this to no avail, as each time I enter my Python interactive I get:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mechanize
>>>
```

The installations I ran previously reported that they had completed successfully, so I expect the import to work. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't installed to 2.6 (which is default on ubuntu? (at least it's on my debian)

Comment: well, the output from easy install shows it's installed to 2.7: Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20130112-py2.7.egg

Comment: I've just tried this every which way -- setup.py, easy_install, pip -- from pypi and the repo, but I can't get it to fail.  Could you check `sys.path` to see if you're looking in the right places, `ls -laR /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mech*`to check for permissions trouble, and look at `imp.find_module("mechanize")` to distinguish between can't-find-it and can't-survive-importing-it errors?

Comment: @DSM added this info to original post

Comment: @RoybertSoylend: thanks.  Unfortunately that rules out both of the two theories I was considering. :-/

Comment: See discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation/34797844?noredirect=1

Comment: did you try installing it with `conda`?

Comment: For me pip install my_package was consistently failing; could see it there with pip list, but would not import into my python 3 program.  Fixed it simply by uninstalling then pip3 install my_package

Comment: Related: [Installing a pip package from within a Jupyter Notebook not working](/q/38368318/4518341) [ipython] [anaconda] + [conda]

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In my case, it is permission problem. The package was somehow installed with root rw permission only, other user just cannot rw to it!

Comment: This happened to me, just running `sudo pip install ...`. Simple fix: `sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: I have run into this many times and I think I just discovered the reason:  umask is passed through sudo, so if your personal umask is tight and you use sudo for the install, the files and directories will be over-restricted.  If you simply su first and then do the install from a full root shell, the resulting install is usable (at least it is for me).  This was for pip, but may apply to apt-get as well.  If others confirm this cause, may want to amend the answer accordingly?

Comment: Adding to jozxyqk comment's: make sure you got the right directory by doing $ pip show <package_name>

Comment: Same for me. I am working with Python 3.6 on Mac, so `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` did the trick

Comment: sudo 777 is always very bad idea

Comment: Ah you're a genius! I installed without sudo but then when I ran my program I used sudo. So obvious now lol

Comment: I had this issue as well, it's caused by a  bad umask.  You can fix the umask for the entire machine if you want.  In my case since I was doing the install via ansible I added a umask argument to the ansible task.

Answer (score 134):

I had the same problem: script with `import colorama` was throwing an `ImportError`, but `sudo pip install colorama` was telling me "package already installed".

My fix: run pip **without sudo**: `pip install colorama`.  Then pip agreed it needed to be installed, installed it, and my script ran. Or even better, use `python -m pip install <package>`.  The benefit of this is, since you are executing the specific version of python that you want the package in, pip will unequivocally install the package into the "right" python.  Again, *don't* use `sudo` in this case... then you get the package in the right place, but possibly with (unwanted) root permissions.

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit; I think I saw this before and after I activated my virtualenv.

Comment: alternatively you can use sudo's -H flag

Comment: Thanks, `python -m pip install <package>` show my problem.

Comment: The reason it changed without `sudo` is because of activating your virtualenv. That changes **which executable named `pip`** is used, to the one that will install packages **to the Python in the virtualenv**. Without the virtualenv activated, `pip` will find a version of Pip that installs **to the Python that came with your operating system** - which is **dangerous, and exactly why you need `sudo`**. You should effectively never do this. Many distributions of Linux deliberately remove Pip from the system Python.

Comment: Somehow `pip` and `python` pointed to separate distro or versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

It's the python path problem.

In my case, I have python installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python,
```

and there is no site-packages directory within the python2.6.

The package(SOAPpy) I installed by pip is located

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

And site-package is not in the python path, all I did is add site-packages to PYTHONPATH permanently.

1. Open up Terminal
2. Type open .bash_profile
3. In the text file that pops up, add this line at the end:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
   ```
4. Save the file, restart the Terminal, and you're done

Comment: This worked for me in getting Jenkins working with selenium python.

Comment: This worked for me in running celery through supervisor, when my bash script called my celery script; celery script couldn't import the already installed modules inside my pip. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Note: another possibility of the import error is that you have multiple versions of Python installed in your computer. For example, one from the system's Python and one from Miniconda or Anaconda. Therefore, be sure always to use the correct corresponding "pip".

Answer (score 31):

I was able to correct this issue with a combined approach. First, I followed Chris' advice, opened a command line and typed 'pip show packagename'
This provided the location of the installed package.

Next, I opened python and typed 'import sys', then 'sys.path' to show where my python searches for any packages I import. Alas, the location shown in the first step was NOT in the list.

Final step, I typed 'sys.path.append('package_location_seen_in_step_1'). You optionally can repeat step two to see the location is now in the list.

Test step, try to import the package again... it works.

The downside? It is temporary, and you need to add it to the list each time.

Answer (score 30):

The Python import mechanism works, really, so, either:

1. Your PYTHONPATH is wrong,
2. Your library is not installed where you think it is
3. You have another library with the same name masking this one

Comment: It can't be option 3 in this case; that would not throw an ImportError.

Comment: maybe 2? I just don't know why it would install in the wrong place for this one library, where most others are fine.

Comment: Option 4: Your PYTHONPATH is right, your library is where you want it, you don't have a library masking this... but because you used `sudo pip install` it got installed with root privs, and at import time something is bombing for the lack of read or write access.

Comment: Not quite true, @MartijnPieters: if there was an import of the form "from <package> import <foo>", and if the obstructing package had no "foo", then you'd get an import error for option 3.

Comment: @DanH sure, but that's not the form the OP is using.

Comment: Option 3 is totally valid!

Comment: For "Option 3", please see [What can I do about "ImportError: Cannot import name X" or "AttributeError: ... (most likely due to a circular import)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543).

Comment: And this is it! This is the answer. I previously installed a package that had a name identical to the new module I was trying to install. After reading this, I went to the folder where my python (pip) packages are installed and I manually deleted all the packages with the name. Then I did "pip install <PyDictionary>" again and that is solved.

Answer (score 16):

I have been banging my head against my monitor on this until a young-hip intern told me the secret is to "python setup.py install" **inside the module directory.**

For some reason, running the setup from there makes it just work.

To be clear, if your module's name is "foo":

```
[burnc7 (2016-06-21 15:28:49) git]# ls -l
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  118 Jun 21 15:22 foo
[burnc7 (2016-06-21 15:28:51) git]# cd foo
[burnc7 (2016-06-21 15:28:53) foo]# ls -l
total 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   93 Jun 21 15:23 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  416 May 31 12:26 setup.py
[burnc7 (2016-06-21 15:28:54) foo]# python setup.py install
<--snip-->
```

If you try to run setup.py from any other directory by calling out its path, you end up with a borked install.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
python /root/foo/setup.py install
```

DOES WORK:

```
cd /root/foo
python setup.py install
```

Comment: This will depend on what the `setup.py` script actually does - it's Python code, after all. **If** the directory matters, it's because the code in the script is expecting a specific CWD - for example, because it's trying to open or move files using relative paths. Aside from that, though, this is **only** relevant for installing from source that you already have downloaded (or checked out from a repository), and **only** for `setup.py` based installs. It is not relevant for newer `pyproject.toml`-based installs, and not relevant for installing with `pip` from PyPI.

Comment: Nowadays, `setup.py` **should not be run directly at all** - it should only be invoked via `setuptools`. This is part of the long-term migration of the Python package-installation paradigm.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this while trying to use keyring which I installed via `sudo pip install keyring`. As mentioned in the other answers, it's a permissions issue in my case.

What worked for me:

1. Uninstalled keyring:

- `sudo pip uninstall keyring`

2. I used sudo's `-H` option and reinstalled keyring:

- `sudo -H pip install keyring`

Answer (score 6):

In PyCharm, I fixed this issue by changing the project interpreter path.

`File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`

`File -> Invalidate Caches…` may be required afterwards.

Comment: Or here's a shortcut way, if you are using PyCharm: Just `File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Available Packages` and search for your desired package here and simply click install.

Answer (score 6):

Check that you are using the same python version in the interpreter of your IDE or code editor and on your system.
For example, check your python version in the terminal with `python3 --version`
And check python version for interpreter in VSCode by `cmd+shift+p`-> Python: Select interpreter -> select the same version as you see in your terminal.[image]

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get my PYTHONPATH to work properly.  I realized adding `export` fixed the issue:

(did work)

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/test/site-packages
```

vs.

(did not work)

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/test/site-packages
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem can also occur with a relocated virtual environment (venv).

I had a project with a venv set up inside the root directory. Later I created a new user and decided to move the project to this user. Instead of moving only the source files and installing the dependencies freshly, I moved the entire project along with the venv folder to the new user.

After that, the dependencies that I installed were getting added to the global `site-packages` folder instead of the one inside the venv, so the code running inside this env was not able to access those dependencies.

To solve this problem, just remove the venv folder and recreate it again, like so:

```
$ deactivate
$ rm -rf venv
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: "After that the dependencies that I installed were getting added to the global site-packages instead of the one inside venv folder." This happens because the venv is not active. However, it is true that venvs are not designed to be relocatable. The code here suggests that you are on a Linux system. It should not be possible to add anything to the "global" `site-packages` without using `sudo`. (**Do not do that.**)

Answer (score 3):

Something that worked for me was:

```
python -m pip install -user {package name}
```

The command does not require sudo. This was tested on OSX Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had run `pip install Django==1.11` and it would not import from the `python` interpreter.

Browsing through pip's commands I found `pip show` which looked like this:

```
> pip show Django
Name: Django
Version: 1.11
...
Location: /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
...
```

Notice the location says '3.4'. I found that the `python`-command was linked to `python2.7`

```
/usr/bin> ls -l python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 14 15:48 python -> python2.7
```

Right next to that I found a link called `python3` so I used that. You could also change the link to `python3.4`. That would fix it, too.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a problem with a missing `__init__.py` file in the module, that I wanted to import in a Python 2.7 environment.

Python 3.3+ has Implicit Namespace Packages that allow it to create a packages without an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem too. The package was installed on Python 3.8.0 but VS Code was running my script using an older version (3.4)

fix in terminal:

```
py <yourfile>.py
```

Make sure you're installing the package on the right Python version.

Answer (score 2):

I had colorama installed via pip and I was getting "ImportError: No module named colorama"

So I searched with "find", found the absolute path and added it in the script like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/")
import colorama
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had just the same problem, and updating `setuptools` helped:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

After that, reinstall the package, and it should work fine :)

The thing is, the package is built incorrectly if `setuptools` is old.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem (on Windows) and the root cause in my case was **ANTIVIRUS** software! It has "Auto-Containment" feature, that wraps running process with some kind of a virtual machine.
Symptoms are: `pip install somemodule` works fine in one cmd-line window and `import somemodule` fails when executed from another process with the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somemodule'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers mentioned do not work for you, try deleting your pip cache and reinstalling the package. My machine runs Ubuntu14.04 and it was located under `~/.cache/pip`. Deleting this folder did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you do not confuse `pip3` with `pip`. What I found was that package installed with `pip` was not working with `python3` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (an Ubuntu 20.04 VM on WIN10 Host), I have a disordered situation with many version of Python installed and variuos point of Shared Library (installed with pip in many points of the File System). I'm referring to 3.8.10 Python version.
After many tests, I've found a suggestion searching with google (but' I'm sorry, I haven't the link). This is what I've done to resolve the problem :

1. From shell session on Ubuntu 20.04 VM, (inside the Home, in my case   /home/hduser), I've started a Jupyter Notebook session with the command "jupyter notebook".
2. Then, when jupyter was running I've opened a .ipynb file to give commands.
3. First : pip list --> give me the list of packages installed, and, sympy
   wasn't present (although I had installed it with "sudo pip install sympy"
   command.
4. Last with the command !pip3 install sympy (inside jupyter notebook
   session) I've solved the problem, here the screen-shot :
   [image]
5. Now, with !pip list the package "sympy" is present, and working :
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I assumed a package was installed because it showed up in the output of `pip freeze`. However, just the `site-packages/*.dist-info` folder is enough for pip to list it as installed despite missing the actual package contents (perhaps from an accidental deletion). This happens *even when* all the path settings are correct, and if you try `pip install <pkg>` it will say "requirement already satisfied".

The solution is to manually remove the `dist-info` folder so that pip realizes the package contents are missing. Then, doing a fresh install should re-populate anything that was accidentally removed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but I had a similar issue on Mac M1 with zsh. Turns out I had set an alias command in my .zshrc file with the same name as my python command (python3).

To solve the issue, I just had to unalias the command. I ran:

```
unalias python3
```

both from my home terminal and from the terminal in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When you install via `easy_install` or `pip`, is it completing successfully? What is the full output? Which python installation are you using? You may need to use `sudo` before your installation command, if you are installing modules to a system directory (if you are using the system python installation, perhaps). There's not a lot of useful information in your question to go off of, but some tools that will probably help include:

- `echo $PYTHONPATH` and/or `echo $PATH`: when importing modules, Python searches one of these environment variables (lists of directories, `:` delimited) for the module you want. Importing problems are often due to the right directory being absent from these lists
- `which python`, `which pip`, or `which easy_install`: these will tell you the location of each executable. It may help to know.
- **Use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)**, like @JesseBriggs suggests. It works very well with `pip` to help you isolate and manage the modules and environment for separate Python projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, but none of the answers above worked. It drove me crazy until I noticed that sys.path was different after I had imported from the parent project. It turned out that I had used importlib to write a little function in order to import a file not in the project hierarchy. Bad idea: I forgot that I had done this. Even worse, the import process mucked with the sys.path--and left it that way. *Very* bad idea.

The solution was to stop that, and simply put the file I needed to import into the project. Another approach would have been to put the file into its own project, as it needs to be rebuilt from time to time, and the rebuild may or may not coincide with the rebuild of the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with 2.7 and 3.5 installed on my system trying to test a telegram bot with [Python-Telegram-Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot](asd)).

I couldn't get it to work after installing with pip and pip3, with sudo or without. I always got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telegram.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater
  File "$USER/telegram.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater
ImportError: No module named 'telegram.ext'; 'telegram' is not a package
```

Reading the error message correctly tells me that python is looking in the current directory for a `telegram.py`. And right, I had a script lying there called telegram.py and this was loaded by python when I called `import`.

Conclusion, make sure you don't have any `package.py` in your current working dir when trying to import. (And read error message thoroughly).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Django. In my case, I could import the module from the Django shell, but not from a .py which imported the module.
The problem was that I was running the Django server (therefore, executing the .py) from a **different virtualenv** from which the module had been installed.

Instead, the shell instance was being run in the correct virtualenv. Hence, why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This Works!!!

This often happens when module is installed to an older version of python or another directory, no worries as solution is simple.
 - import module from directory in which module is installed.
You can do this by first importing the python `sys` module then importing from the path in which the module is installed

```
import sys
sys.path.append("directory in which module is installed")

import <module_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the possible cases have been already covered in solutions, just sharing my case, it happened to me that I installed a package in one environment (e.g. `X`) and I was importing the package in another environment (e.g. `Y`). So, always make sure that you're importing the package from the environment in which you installed the package.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was ensuring the version of the module aligned with the version of Python I was using.. I built the image on a box with Python **3.6** and then injected into a Docker image that happened to have **3.7** installed, and then banging my head when Python was telling me the module wasn't installed...

`36m` for Python 3.6
`bsonnumpy.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

`37m` for Python 3.7 `bsonnumpy.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: `pip install` the version that matches the version of Python you are using. What error do you get, and what is the output of `python --version`

Comment: python --version gives me : Python 3.7.7 and when I chek where the package are installed with pip show librosa  gives ; Location: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
how means that the package are in the right place, but when I import the package gives : no module name
I am working on the AWS Sagemaker env Pytorch_p36

Comment: presumably you want to be using pytorch_p37 ?

Comment: there's no pytorch_p37

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old post but for me, I had an issue with a 32 bit python and 64 bit python installed. Once I uninstalled the 32 bit python, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue that same libraries were working fine in one project(A) but importing those same libraries in another project(B) caused error. I am using Pycharm as IDE at Windows OS.
So, after trying many potential solutions and failing to solve the issue, I did these two things (deleted "Venv" folder, and reconfigured interpreter):

1-In project(B), there was a folder named("venv"), located in External Libraries/. I deleted that folder.

2-Step 1 (deleting "venv" folder) causes error in Python Interpreter Configuration, and 
  there is a message shown at top of screen saying "Invalid python interpreter selected 
  for the project" and "configure python interpreter", select that link and it opens a 
  new window. There in "Project Interpreter" drop-down list, there is a Red colored line 
  showing previous invalid interpreter. Now, Open this list and select the Python 
  Interpreter(in my case, it is Python 3.7). Press "Apply" and "OK" at the bottom and you 
  are good to go.

Note: It was potentially the issue where Virtual Environment of my Project(B) was not recognizing the already installed and working libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As a friend did for me today, here is what helped me (I am using Windows):

Press 'Setting' -> 'Project' -> 'Project Interpreter'. Here in the window on the right, there is a line with the title 'Project Interpreter' on it's left. Click this line and it will open several additional lines.

Now press the 'Show All' line. A window will open. 
In this window press the small '+' sign in the upper right corner.

A new window will open. On the left there are 4 tabs, press the most upper one, which says 'Virtualenv Environment'. 
Now, in the window on the right, mark the 'Existing Environment' option. The 'Interpreter' line will become well visible. Press the '...' button on the right of the line.

Now, a browsing window will open. Browse to **the directory that you installed Python itself in**. Not the one with PyCharm. When you get there, choose the 'python.exe' file and press OK (the window will disappear).

Press OK again (this window will disappear too).

Now in this window make sure the new line you created is marked, and press OK again.

Now, all the installed packages should be visible in the project interpreter, and are read by your program.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is very old post but I didn't find any answer that was useful in my case (I am using arch linux).
I had a similar problem installing "nest_asyncio" package which was definitely installed (visible when listing all the installed packages). There is a right  way for arch linux users of installing python packages (as it was already explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76389/recommended-way-of-installing-python-packages-on-arch) by [Emanuel Fontelles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/289968/emanuel-fontelles)).
In my case the solution was just to uninstall the remaining not-working package (in my case "nest_asyncio") and then installing it again using the following command:

`sudo pacman -S python-"nest_asyncio`

That solved all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I found that package `setup.py` would produce this problem too.

I have a setup with `classifiers < 3`

```
setup(
    name='data_reader',
    version='0.1',

    description='data_reader by Mithril ',
    long_description=long_description,

    author='Mithril',

    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 1 - Beta',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',

        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',

        "License :: GPLv3",

        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Tools',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],


)
```

And I was using python 3.7 in a conda env, I found

```
pip install .
# or
pip install git+https://github.com/eromoe/data_reader
```

All successed, however `import data_reader` raise `not found` .

After some testing, dig that only after changing `classifiers` to

```
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 1 - Beta',
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        "License :: GPLv3",
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Tools',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
```

Install again, the import became normal!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling the following command on the terminal

> eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit off-topic, but i had issues to `import PyYAML`. Points out that you need to `import yaml`. (guess it's a classical rtfm...)

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to also install the module(s) for the superuser, too.

```
sudo su
pip install <module>
```

Apparently the superuse cannot access the normal users files under certain circumstances.

Comment: don't use pip with sudo.

Comment: @xotix If I need to run a python script as sudo, installing the required modules as sudo is the easiest solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a virtual environment use `pipenv install <module name>` instead of `pip install <module name>`

Worked for me.

Comment: pipenv not found

Comment: `pipenv` is a separate package and way of doing things that doesn't have anything to do with the question asked. https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution that worked for me that I don't see mentioned in this thread:

I have multiple versions of Python installed but was trying to use Python3.7 -- so I had to use:

`sudo pip3.7 install <package>`

Comment: don't ever use pip with sudo. This makes your package manager sad. Maybe if you use pip, try the --user flag.

Comment: xotix, could you elaborate on why somebody should be concerned about the feelings of a package manager? if you're trying to say that you should follow the principle of least privilege and it's not necessary, then maybe you should say that.