# python pip error pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, pip, reinstall

I'm trying to install a new module, but I found that `pip` doesn't work - it shows

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

for each call I performed. Also, for `pip --help`. I found some advises to reinstall `pip` using `pip` or `easy_install`, but `easy_install` doesn't works too:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==5.7' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Is there a way to fix this issue without reinstalling `python` and all its modules?
I have Linux Ubuntu 14.04.
`apt-get install python-pip` suggests installing `pip` (and a heap of another following software) like I don't have it in my system. I afraid to do it, would be a conflict here?

**Upd.**
`apt-get` says that it want to install the following: `build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libfakeroot libstdc++-4.8-dev python-chardet-whl python-colorama python-colorama-whl  python-distlib python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-pip python-pip-whl python-requests-whl python-setuptools python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl python-wheel`. But as I know pip worked for me without these packages.
Also I performed
`which -a python`: `/usr/bin/python`
`which -a pip`: `/usr/local/bin/pip`
`python --version`: `Python 2.7.6`

Comment: please include the output of `which -a python` and `which -a pip` in your question. Also you may want to be more specific about the packages pulled in by `apt-get install python-pip`, but which you don't want to have on your system.

Comment: I edited my question before

Comment: Yes, but you did not really answer my question. Which of those are problematic for you? Basically you have two good options: 1) Accept, that ubuntu is installing more than the bare minimum needed to run pip. 2) Switch to a virtualenv and therefore avoid using `apt` to install python dependencies.

Comment: You may also want to read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32680082/2272172) which will explain why `pip` installing will not work for you. Please note, I would advice against installing into `/usr/bin/python` with `pip`.

Comment: Ok, I've installed `pip` via `apt-get` and ... nothing changed. I still can't run `pip` and not to receive error

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful to have the full backtrace of the error. One scenario that can lead to this issue, is having multiple versions of Python installed.

For example, on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I have installed Python 3.6 from source, in addition to Python 3.8 distributed with Ubuntu 20. This is what I get with `pip3 --version` after installing Python 3.6:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 581, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 898, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 789, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3126, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3110, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3139, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 784, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

The last line is the error in question, but notice an important detail in the traceback: `raise VersionConflict`.

This can be solved by [explicitly using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/5362795) the required version of `pip`:

```
$ python3.6 -m pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Or simply:

```
$ pip3.6 --version
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Another issue one may stumble upon, is the [missing lsb_release](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003535) issue when doing `pip3.6 install`:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

This can be solved by locating `lsb_release.py` and creating a symlink, for example:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

Now it's possible to upgrade pip3.6 and install new packages:

```
$ pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
$ pip3.6 install mypy
```

There are different methods for [managing Python versions](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/). Beware of using something like `sudo update-alternatives --config python`. Changing the system's default Python, will likely cause problems, including symptoms like the terminal not opening. It's good to have a backup terminal available, such as the one in Visual Studio Code.